# Anonymous recursive function in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, anonymous-function

Is there a way to write an anonymous function that is recursive in Scala? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
((t: Tree) => {
    print(t.value);
    for (c <- t.children)
        thisMethod(c)
})(root)
```

(Related question: [Which languages support *recursive* function literals / anonymous functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156369/which-languages-support-recursive-function-literals-anonymous-functions))

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As described in the link you posted. You can use Y-combinator. Here is example:

```
scala> def fix[A,B](f: (A=>B)=>(A=>B)): A=>B = f(fix(f))(_)
fix: [A,B](f: ((A) => B) => (A) => B)(A) => B

scala> val fact = fix[Int,Int](f => a => if(a<=0) 1 else f(a-1) * a)
fact: (Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> fact(12)
res0: Int = 479001600
```

Note it doesn't work with big numbers. 
Be careful with tail call optimization.

Comment: "Amazing" in the original sense of making me feel like I'm lost in a maze.  `fix` is a function takes as input a function that itself takes a single argument and returns another function that takes a single argument, and then it ...  OK, I'm going to need a better explanation from *somebody*...

Comment: But this does not allow tail call optimization, am I correct?

Comment: @Malvolio: `fix` is a function which takes another function `f` as its argument and returns a _fixed point_ for that function, i.e. a value `x` for which `f(x) == x`. Functions which compute fixed points for other functions are called [fixed point combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator). The Y-combinator is just one example of a fixed point combinator. Fixed point combinators offer a way to describe recursion in languages such as the lambda calculus which don't allow self-referential definitions.

Answer (score 27):

If you don't want to hit the "Amazing mathematics" you could just revert to the object aspects of scala.

```
val fact = new Function1[Int,Int]{
    def apply(x:Int):Int = if(x==1) x else x * apply(x-1)
}
```

Answer (score 16):

in order to make it look geekier you can also use this code style:

```
val fact = new ((Int) => Int){
  def apply(x:Int):Int = if(x==1) x else x * apply(x-1)
}
```

Comment: This one looks much better than simply `new Function[Int, Int] {...}`. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the many good responses here in this thread, the fact that Scala is not giving us tail call optimizable Fixed-point combinator has been bothering me so much so that I've decided to write a macro to translate Y-combinator-like call to an ordinary, idiomatic recursive call (with tail call optimization, of course). The idea is that a call like

```
fix[Int,Int]((next) => (y) => ...body...)
```

is readily translatable into

```
({(input) =>
  object next {
    def apply(y:Int):Int = ...body...
  }
  next(input)
})
```

I've put up macro implementation targeting Scala 2.11 (with minor tweak should also work with 2.10) into [this gist](https://gist.github.com/chajath/5e1cab0825ce1207d68e).

With this macro, we can perform ordinary recursive tasks in anonymous manner without fearing stack overflow e.g.

```
import asia.blip.ymacro.YMacro._
(y[BigInt,BigInt]((xx) => (y) => if(y==1) 1 else y * xx(y-1)))(2000)
```

gives

```
res0: BigInt = 33162750924506332411753933805763240382811...
```

Comment: I guess I'm still wondering whether you can add the tailrec annotation so it can have the tail call optimization.

Comment: @JoshCason think Scala is smart enough to infer tailrec in the example that I gave. I'm not too sure about more involved use cases to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive calls on Scala.
**Let me take sum of N numbers example for recursion**

```
var sumIt:(Int => Int) = (x: Int) => {if(x<=1) 1 else sumIt(x-1)+x}


 scala> sumIt(10) 
val res141: Int = 55
```

You can see the sumIt has its type with Int, Int as Input and the return value. The sumIt lambda function takes as argument which is an Integer and it does recursive call on sumIt.

> I just this example for easy understanding the recursion call. You can direct formula for this logic like...

```
sumValue = (N*(N+1)) /2
```

Answer (score 0):

To add onto @in-ho-yi 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25642408). For simplicity you can directly define a local function inside of an anonymous function and use it for recursion. Also using `@tailrec` before the local function you can make sure it will apply tail recursion which you can't do with the Y-combinator.

This is a better approach than Y-combinator because it only adds 2 frames to the stack and 1 per call of the function (if it's not tail recursive, if it is it will only add 1 in total so 3 frames max will be used) instead of 6 per call that Y-combinator uses

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

val fact = {(input: BigInt)=>
  @tailrec
  def f(x:BigInt, acc: BigInt = 1):BigInt = {
    if(x<=1) acc
    else f(x-1, x*acc)
  }
  f(input)
}

print(fact(1024))
```

Answer (score -1):

A very simple approach:

```
val fact = { (x: Int) =>
  def f(x: Int): Int = if (x == 0) 1 else x * f(x-1)
  f(x)
}

// Use as anonymous function below
(1 to 5).map { (x: Int) =>
  def f(x: Int): Int = if (x == 0) 1 else x * f(x-1)
  f(x)
}

// res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 6, 24, 120)
```

Comment: The recursive function is `f`, which is not anonymous. The fact that it's defined inside of an anonymous function does not change that.

Comment: The downvote is unwarranted as the solution serves the purpose intended by the question.  In addition, you singled-out this solution while there are two other solutions above very similar to this one that use def apply instead of def f.

Comment: Is your solution more correct the way it is than if `def f` were moved up one line? Because if no that illustrates my point, and if yes explain why they aren't exactly the same except for f's scope