# How do I write recursive anonymous functions?

Tags: scala, recursion, anonymous-function

In my continued effort to learn scala, I'm working through 'Scala by example' by Odersky and on the chapter on first class functions, the section on anonymous function avoids a situation of recursive anonymous function. I have a solution that seems to work. I'm curious if there is a better answer out there.

From the pdf:
Code to showcase higher order functions

```
def sum(f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int =
  if (a > b) 0 else f(a) + sum(f, a + 1, b)

def id(x: Int): Int = x
def square(x: Int): Int = x * x
def powerOfTwo(x: Int): Int = if (x == 0) 1 else 2 * powerOfTwo(x-1)

def sumInts(a: Int, b: Int): Int = sum(id, a, b)
def sumSquares(a: Int, b: Int): Int = sum(square, a, b)
def sumPowersOfTwo(a: Int, b: Int): Int = sum(powerOfTwo, a, b)

scala> sumPowersOfTwo(2,3)
res0: Int = 12
```

from the pdf:
Code to showcase anonymous functions

```
def sum(f: Int => Int, a: Int, b: Int): Int =
  if (a > b) 0 else f(a) + sum(f, a + 1, b)

def sumInts(a: Int, b: Int): Int = sum((x: Int) => x, a, b)
def sumSquares(a: Int, b: Int): Int = sum((x: Int) => x * x, a, b)
// no sumPowersOfTwo
```

My code:

```
def sumPowersOfTwo(a: Int, b: Int): Int = sum((x: Int) => {
   def f(y:Int):Int = if (y==0) 1 else 2 * f(y-1); f(x) }, a, b)

scala> sumPowersOfTwo(2,3)
res0: Int = 12
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? `echo "2^2+3^2" | bc -l` --> `13`.

Comment: This is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337464/anonymous-recursive-function-in-scala

Comment: @sarnold Sum of Powers of Two - i.e `2^a + 2^a+1 + .... 2^b-1 + 2^b` `2^2+2^3 = 4+8 = 12`

Comment: @James, ah. I'll hang my head in shame and leave the comment to hopefully help others avoid the same shame.

Comment: I don't understand what's `anonymous` with this functions.

Comment: There is always the Y-Combinator: http://www.scala-blogs.org/2008/09/y-combinator-in-scala.html

Comment: @userunknown, `(x: Int) => x * x` is an anonymous function in the definition of `sumSquares`

Comment: Would `multiply (x, x)` be an anonymous function too? `x.times (x)`?

Answer (score 13):

For what it's worth... (the title and "real question" don't quite agree)

**Recursive anonymous function-objects can be created through the "long hand" extending of `FunctionN`** and then using `this(...)` inside `apply`.

```
(new Function1[Int,Unit] {
  def apply(x: Int) {
    println("" + x)
    if (x > 1) this(x - 1)
  }
})(10)
```

However, the amount of icky-ness this generally introduces makes the approach generally less than ideal. Best just use a "name" and have some more descriptive, modular code -- not that the following is a very good argument for such ;-)

```
val printingCounter: (Int) => Unit = (x: Int) => {
    println("" + x)
    if (x > 1) printingCounter(x - 1)
}
printingCounter(10)
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can generalize this indirect recursion to:

```
case class Rec[I, O](fn : (I => O, I) => O) extends (I => O) {
  def apply(v : I) = fn(this, v)
}
```

Now sum can be written using indirect recursion as:

```
val sum = Rec[Int, Int]((f, v) => if (v == 0) 0 else v + f(v - 1))
```

The same solution can be used to implement memoization for example.