# Define recursive lambda expression in scala

Tags: scala, lambda

I am trying to define a recursive lambda expression in scala and struggling a bit with sintax, if think that this is just a syntax:
Here is what I have so far (not compilable):

```
type rec = (Int => Int, Int)
val f = (x : Int) => x + x
val y : rec = (f:Int => Int, x:Int) => if (x > 0) y( f, 1) else 1

Error I am getting: 
ScalaFiddle.scala:14: error: ScalaFiddle.rec does not take parameters
  val y : rec = (f:Int => Int, x:Int) => if (x > 0) y( f, 1) else 1
                                                 ^
```

Original code sample I am trying to optimize (which works fine):

```
case class Rec[I, O](fn : (I => O, I) => O) extends (I => O) {
  def apply(v : I) = fn(this, v)
}

val sum = Rec[Int, Int]((f, v) => if (v == 0) 0 else v + f(v - 1))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: rec is a tuple of a Int => Int function and a integer. by `y(f,1)` you are trying to call a function on a tuple. tuple doesnt have a apply function defined on it.

Comment: so, does that means that I have to follow original code sample way? to define apply in the type ? or I can do this in the lambda some how?

Comment: yes your original code sample is type complaint. you should follow that approach. The original code is quite optimized let us know what further optimization you are looking for

Comment: so, as I understand I can NOT extend tuple within lambda expression? so this has to be expresses separately? thats ok then

Comment: updated my answer that corrects your type rec definition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anonymous recursive function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337464/anonymous-recursive-function-in-scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rec is a tuple of type `Tuple2[Int => Int,Int]`.

in your statement `val y : rec = (f:Int => Int, x:Int) => if (x > 0) y( f, 1) else 1`, you are trying to call a apply function on the tuple y (`y(f,1)`). Since the tuple doesnt have a apply function defined you are getting the error `rec does not take parameters`

as per your sample code your type rec `(Int => Int, Int) => Int`.

so the code sample would be

```
type rec = (Int => Int, Int) => Int
val f = (x : Int) => x + x
val y : rec = (f:Int => Int, x:Int) => if (x > 0) y( f, 1) else 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check This link for this answer explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337464/anonymous-recursive-function-in-scala/61557522#61557522)

```
var sumIt:(Int => Int) = (x: Int) => {if(x<=1) 1 else sumIt(x-1)+x
```

Comment: You could also directly flag the question as duplicated. Thanks anyway for the hint.

Comment: @dboy They can't. [Flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) requires 15 reputation points :)