# How to write/code several functions as one

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a line composed of two segments as a single equation in [image]:

```
y = m1*x + c1 , for x<=x1
y = m2*x + c2 , for x>=x1
```

My questions are:

1. How can I write the function of this combined line as a single equation?
2. How can I write multiple functions (valid in separate regions of a linear parameter space) as a single equation?

Please explain both how to express this mathematically and how to program this in general and in Matlab specifically.

Comment: Yes it Piece-wise linear. I want to know , is it possible to represent [A to B] with a single equation ? If yes , what is it ?

Comment: For the record, you **could** hack it up by checking the `x` coordinate of the breakpoint, and using Heaviside functions to choose from the two formulae for `x` smaller and larger then the breakpoint... But still not programming. I mean `y(x)=H(x1-x)*(m1*x+c1) + H(x-x1)*(m2*x+c2)` where `x1` is the `x` coordinate of the breakpoint...

Comment: @barceloco, giving a thorough answer to an off-topic question, then rewriting the question to include programming. Very smooth:D

Comment: @AndrasDeak touché :-) We need to keep the quality of these questions high and on topic, right? ;-)

Comment: @barceloco sure, but I have to remove my downvote now:P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this equation as a single line by using the Heaviside step function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function.

**Combining two functions into one:**

In fact, what you are trying to do is

```
f(x) = a(x)   (for x < x1)
f(x) = q      (for x = x1), where q = a(x1) = b(x1)
f(x) = b(x)   (for x > x1)
```

The (half-maximum) Heaviside function is defined as

```
H(x) = 0      (for x < 0)
H(x) = 0.5    (for x = 0)
H(x) = 1      (for x > 0)
```

Hence, your function will be

```
f(x) = H(x1-x) * a(c) + H(x-x1) * b(x)
```

and, therefore,

```
f(x) = H(x1-x) * (m1*x+c1) + H(x-x1) * (m2x+c2)
```

If you want to *implement this*, note that many programming languages will allow you to write something like

```
f(x) = (x<x1)?a(x):b(x)
```

which means if `x<x1`, then return value `a(x)`, else return `b(x)`, or in your case:

```
f(x) = (x<x1)?(m1*x+c1):(m2x+c2)
```

**Matlab implementation:**

In Matlab, you can write simple functions such as

```
a = @(x) m1.*x+c1,
b = @(x) m2.*x+c2,
```

assuming that you have previously defined `m1`, `m2`, and `c1`, `c2`.

There are several ways to using/implementing the Heaviside function

1. If you have the `Symbolic Math Toolbox` for Matlab, you can directly use `heaviside()` as a function.
2. @AndrasDeak (see comments below) pointed out that you can write your own half-maximum Heaviside function `H` in Matlab by entering

   ```
   iif = @(varargin) varargin{2 * find([varargin{1:2:end}], 1, 'first')}();
   H = @(x) iif(x<0,0,x>0,1,true,0.5);
   ```
3. If you want a continuous function that approximates the Heaviside function, you can use a logistic function `H` defined as

   ```
   H = @(x) 1./(1+exp(-100.*x));
   ```

Independently of your implementation of the Heaviside function `H`, you can, create a one-liner in the following way (I am using `x1=0` for simplicity) :

```
a = @(x) 2.*x + 3;
b = @(x) -1.5.*x + 3;
```

Which allows you to write your original function as a one-liner:

```
f = @(x) H(-x).*a(x) + H(x).*b(x);
```

You can then plot this function, for example from -10 to 10 by writing `plot(-10:10, f(-10:10))` you will get the plot below.

[image: Example of a plot using the Heaviside/logistic function to combine two linear segments to a single function]

**Generalization:**

Imagine you have

```
f(x) = a(x)   (for x < x1)
f(x) = q      (for x = x1), where q = a(x1) = b(x1)
f(x) = b(x)   (for x1 < x < x2)
f(x) = r      (for x = x2), where r = b(x2) = c(x2)
f(x) = c(x)   (for x2 < x < x3)
f(x) = s      (for x = x2), where s = c(x3) = d(x3)
f(x) = d(x)   (for x3 < x)
```

By multiplying Heaviside functions, you can now determine zones where specific functions will be computed.

```
f(x) = H(x1-x)*a(c) + H(x-x1)*H(x2-x)*b(x) + H(x-x2)*H(x3-x)*c(x) + H(x-x3)*d(x)
```

PS: just realized that one of the comments above talks about the Heaviside function, too. Kudos to @AndrasDeak .

Comment: Note that specifically matlab has a function called `heaviside` with the convention `heaviside(0)==0.5`

Comment: @AndrasDeak : correct, thanks for pointing this out. In fact, people can purchase the `Symbolic Math Toolbox`, which contains the `heaviside()` function. The logistic function described above is a good approximation, but if you have the `Symbolic Math Toolbox`, go with `heaviside` directly :-)

Comment: You're completely right, sorry, for some reason I thought that was a built-in. Well, then I suggest `iif = @(varargin) varargin{2 * find([varargin{1:2:end}], 1, 'first')}(); H=@(x)iif(x<0,0,x>0,1,true,0.5)`:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak : beautiful!! I just learned something. Thanks for showing how to implement the proper Heaviside function in a one-liner. I'll add it to the answer. Cheers

Comment: Well, two-liner to be honest;) I only learned this myself today, see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237198/recursive-anonymous-function-matlab#comment52357295_32237198). Credits go to [@beaker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1377097/beaker) for the find.

Comment: Excellent either way. Thanks!