# Finding the greatest common divisor of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Im looking for a way to divide a certain matrix elements with its lowest common divisor.

for example, I have vectors

```
[0,0,0; 2,4,2;-2,0,8]
```

I can tell the lowest common divisor is 2, so the matrix after the division will be

```
[0,0,0;1,2,1;-1,0,4]
```

What is the built in method that can compute this?

Thanks in advance

p.s. I personally do not like using loops for this computation, it seems like there is built in computation that can perform matrix element division.

Comment: you just want the code for the division, not to find the lowest common divisor, right?

Comment: @Max Well to be honest, finding the lowest common divisor would be great as well

Comment: Might want to change your question title then, because the answer to that question is `A/a`.

Comment: I second the suggestion of @JJMDriessen, since the part about `A/a` is trivial if you start learning any matlab. But the "vector's gcd" part is much more interesting, and the answers all focus on that.

Comment: @JJM Driessen, Andras Deak Yes, this new title looks much better, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't like loops, how about recursive functions?

```
iif = @(varargin) varargin{2 * find([varargin{1:2:end}], 1, 'first')}();
gcdrec=@(v,gcdr) iif(length(v)==1,v, ...
                     v(1)==1,1, ...
                     length(v)==2,@()gcd(v(1),v(2)), ...
                     true,@()gcdr([gcd(v(1),v(2)),v(3:end)],gcdr));
mygcd=@(v)gcdrec(v(:)',gcdrec);

A=[0,0,0; 2,4,2;-2,0,8];
divisor=mygcd(A);
A=A/divisor;
```

The first function `iif` will define an inline conditional construct. This allows to define a recursive function, `gcdrec`, to find the greatest common divisor of your array. This [`iif`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237198/recursive-anonymous-function-matlab) works like this: it tests whether the first argument is `true`, if it is, then it returns the second argument. Otherwise it tests the third argument, and if *that's* `true`, then it returns the fourth, and so on. You need to protect recursive functions and sometimes other quantities appearing inside it with `@()`, otherwise you can get errors.

Using `iif` the recursive function `gcdrec` works like this:

- if the input vector is a scalar, it returns it
- else if the first component of the vector is 1, there's no chance to recover, so it returns 1 (allows quick return for large matrices)
- else if the input vector is of length 2, it returns the greatest common divisor via `gcd`
- else it calls itself with a shortened vector, in which the first two elements are substituted with their greatest common divisor.

The function `mygcd` is just a front-end for convenience.

Should be pretty fast, and I guess only the recursion depth could be a problem for very large problems. I did a quick timing check to compare with the looping version of @Adriaan, using `A=randi(100,N,N)-50`, with `N=100`, `N=1000` and `N=5000` and `tic`/`toc`.

1. `N=100`:

   - looping  0.008 seconds
   - recursive 0.002 seconds
2. `N=1000`:

   - looping  0.46 seconds
   - recursive 0.04 seconds
3. `N=5000`:

   - looping 11.8 seconds
   - recursive 0.6 seconds

**Update**: interesting thing is that the only reason that I didn't trip the recursion limit (which is by default 500) is that my data didn't have a common divisor. Setting a random matrix and doubling it will lead to hitting the recursion limit already for `N=100`. So for large matrices this won't work. Then again, for small matrices @Adriaan's solution is perfectly fine.

I also tried to rewrite it to half the input vector in each recursive step: this indeed solves the recursion limit problem, but it is *very* slow (2 seconds for `N=100`, 261 seconds for `N=1000`). There might be a middle ground somewhere, where the matrix size is large(ish) and the runtime's not that bad, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Using function I didn't even know existed. No wonder your solution is much better, kudos!

Comment: With the recursion limit of 500, it already trips for `numel(A)>166` if  gcd>1, so the speed tests are misleading. For `A=ones(10)*2` (100 elements), your code takes 0.016 seconds to run (on my crappy laptop, but still).

Comment: @JJMDriessen, exactly, thanks for pointing that out. I did want to do a proper check where there's a common divisor greater than 1, but I was distracted on the way by trying to write another recursive version without hitting the limit (which turned out to be very slow, so I called it a day). Is should check the timing for small matrices, I guess there shouldn't be a huge difference then (and I wouldn't trust the output of tic/toc).

Comment: this is very interesting, I like this answer using recursion. Also using gcd just answered my question on how to find the common divisor, thanks

Comment: @dnTosh I'm glad I could help, but note the limit set by the recursion limit (i.e. vectors max. length of 166). And the problem is that `gcd` only works for 2 scalars, which is why we definitely need some trick on top of that.

Answer (score 5):

```
 A = [0,0,0; 2,4,2;-2,0,8];
 B = 1;
 kk = max(abs(A(:))); % start at the end
 while B~=0 && kk>=0
     tmp = mod(A,kk);
     B = sum(tmp(:));
     kk = kk - 1;
 end
 kk = kk+1;
```

This is probably not the fastest way, but it will do for now. What I did here is initialise some counter, `B`, to store the sum of all elements in your matrix after taking the `mod`. the `kk` is just a counter which runs through integers. [`mod(A,kk)`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) computes the modulus after division for each element in `A`.  Thus, if all your elements are wholly divisible by 2, it will return a 0 for each element. `sum(tmp(:))` then makes a single column out of the modulo-matrix, which is summed to obtain some number. If and only if that number is 0 there is a common divisor, since then all elements in `A` are wholly divisible by `kk`. As soon as that happens your loop stops and your common divisor is the number in `kk`. Since `kk` is decreased every count it is actually one value too low, thus one is added.

Note: I just edited the loop to run *backwards*  since you are looking for the Greatest cd, not the Smallest cd. If you'd have a matrix like `[4,8;16,8]` it would stop at `2`, not `4`. Apologies for that, this works now, though both other solutions here are much faster.

Finally, dividing matrices can be done like this:

```
divided_matrix = A/kk;
```

Comment: thanks, I was having trouble with element 0 in my list, I couldnt use 'min' or 'rdivide' for this matter since it sometimes gave me value of Nan. But this should work thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Beware though of the computational requirement, that's why I added the `maxIter` catch as well. This might become slow for large matrices with large lowest common divisors.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume `maxIter=max(abs(A(:)))`:)

Comment: Even more so: without `maxIter` you do a huge amount of needless calculations if 1 is the winner. So it's paramount to set `maxIter=max(abs(A(:)))`.

Comment: What if `A = [0,3,0; 5,7,6;-5,0,21]`?

Comment: @Divakar there will be no GCD and it will run all the way. Check the updated answer, it now runs backwards from `max(abs(A(:)))`

Comment: @Adriaan Ah nice! Works now :)

Comment: Still a slow and cumbersome behemoth next to your spaceship-speed solution ;)

Comment: @Adriaan Andras's solution is much better though, as my vectorized one has lots of memory footprints, slowing it down.

Comment: @Divakar, if you need vectors longer than 166 (which you quite might), then mine's no use:) We knew it all along that yours is going to be the best anyway:P

Answer (score 4):

Agreed, I don't like the loops either! Let's kill them -

```
unqA = unique(abs(A(A~=0))).';             %//'
col_extent = [2:max(unqA)]';               %//'
B = repmat(col_extent,1,numel(unqA));
B(bsxfun(@gt,col_extent,unqA)) = 0;
divisor = find(all(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@rem,unqA,B)==0,B),2),1,'first');
if isempty(divisor)
    out = A;
else
    out = A/divisor;
end
```

**Sample runs**

Case #1:

```
A =
     0     0     0
     2     4     2
    -2     0     8
divisor =
     2
out =
     0     0     0
     1     2     1
    -1     0     4
```

Case #2:

```
A =
     0     3     0
     5     7     6
    -5     0    21
divisor =
     1
out =
     0     3     0
     5     7     6
    -5     0    21
```

Comment: Does this work for my matrix of `[4,8;16,8]` with finding  `4` and not `2`?

Comment: @Adriaan Yes there was a bug, fixed now! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, this is good way to solve without using loops. I just started using matlab so I'm not very comfortable with the loops yet. This is great

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach. Let `A` be your input array.

1. Get nonzero values of `A` and take their absolute value. Call the resulting vector `B`.
2. Test each number from `1` to `max(B)`, and see if it divides all entries of `B` (that is, if the remainder of the division is zero).
3. Take the largest such number.

Code:

```
A = [0,0,0; 2,4,2;-2,0,8];                  %// data
B = nonzeros(abs(A));                       %// step 1
t = all(bsxfun(@mod, B, 1:max(B))==0, 1);   %// step 2
result = find(t, 1, 'last');                %// step 3
```

Comment: I see, this is decent example. I guess I can also modify this using 'gcd' as well. Thanks

Comment: +1: as an inline function: 
`@(A)find(all(bsxfun(@mod,A(:),1:max(A))==0,1),1,'last')`