# Finding nearest neighbours of radial segments

Tags: algorithm, matlab, geometry, nearest-neighbor, feature-descriptor

First, don't be scared by the looks of this question ;)

I'm trying to implement a shape descriptor in matlab called Circular Blurred Shape Model, and part of this is to get a list of nearest neighbours for every radial segment as can be seen in Figure 1d)

I went for a straight and simple implementation in MATLAB but I'm stuck at Step 5 and 6 of the algorithm, mainly because I can't wrap my head around the definition:

```
Xb{c,s} = {b1, ..., b{c*s}} as the sorted set of the elements in B* 
so that d(b*{c,s}, bi*) <= d(b*{c,s}, bj*), i<j
```

For me this sounds like a cascaded sorting, first sort by ascending distance and then by ascending index, but the nearest neighbours I find are not according to the paper.

[image: Circulare Blurred Shape Model Description Algorithm]

As an example I show you the nearest neighbours I obtain for the segment b{4,1}, this is the one marked "EX" in Figure 1d)

I get the following list of nearest neighbors for b{4,1}: `b{3,2}, b{3,1}, b{3,8}, b{2,1}, b{2,8}`

correct according to the paper would be: `b{4,2}, b{4,8}, b{3,2}, b{3,1}, b{3,8}`

However my points actually are the closest set to the selected segment measured by euclidean distance! The distance `b{4,1} <=> b{2,1}` is smaller than `b{4,1} <=> b{4,2}` or `b{4,1} <=> b{4,8}`...

[image]

And here is my (ugly, but straight forward) MATLAB code:

```
width  = 734;
height = 734;

assert(width == height, 'Image must be square in size!');

% Radius of the correlogram
R = width;

% Number of circles in correlogram
C = 4;

% Number of sections in correlogram
S = 8;

% "width" of ring segments
d = R/C;

% angle of one segment in degrees
g = 360/S;

% set of bins for the circular description of I
B = zeros(C, S);

% centroid coordinates for bins
B_star = zeros(C,S,2);


% calculate centroids of bins
for c=1:C
    for s=1:S
        alpha = deg2rad(max(s-1, 0)*g + g/2);
        r     = d*max((c-1),0) + d/2;

        B_star(c,s,1) = r*cos(alpha);
        B_star(c,s,2) = r*sin(alpha);
    end
end

% create sorted list of bin numbers which fullfill
% d(b{c,s}*, bi*) <= d(b{c,s}, bj*) where i<j

% B_star_dists is a simple square distance matrix for getting
% the distance between two centroids c_i,s_i and c_j,s_j
B_star_dists = zeros(C*S, C*S);
for i=1:C*S
    [c_i, s_i] = ind2sub([C,S], i);
    % x,y centroid coordinates for point i
    b_star_i   = [B_star(c_i, s_i, 1), B_star(c_i, s_i, 2)];

    for j=1:C*S
        [c_j, s_j] = ind2sub([C,S], j);
        % x,y centroid coordinates for point j
        b_star_j   = [B_star(c_j, s_j, 1), B_star(c_j, s_j, 2)];

        % store the euclidean distance between these two centroids
        % in the distance matrix.
        B_star_dists(i,j) = norm(b_star_i - b_star_j);
    end
end

% calculate nearest neighbour "centroids" for each centroid
% B_NN is a cell array, B{idx} gives an array of indexes to the 
% nearest neighbour centroids. 

B_NN = cell(C*S, 1);
for i=1:C*S
    [c_i, s_i] = ind2sub([C,S], i);

    % get a (C*S)x2 matrix of all distances, the first column are the array
    % indexes and the second column are the distances e.g
    % 1   d1
    % 2   d2
    % ..  ..
    % CS  d{c,s}

    dists = [transpose(1:C*S), B_star_dists(:, i)];

    % sort ascending by the distances first (e.g second column) then
    % sort ascending by the array index (e.g first column)
    dists = sortrows(dists, [2,1]);

    % middle section has nine neighbours, set as default
    neighbour_count = 9;

    if c_i == 1
        % inner region has S+3 neighbours
        neighbour_count = S+3;
    elseif c_i == C
        % outer most ring has 6 neighbours
        neighbour_count = 6;
    end

    B_NN{i} = dists(1:neighbour_count,1);
end

% FROM HERE ON JUST VISUALIZATION CODE

figure(1);
hold on;
for c=1:C
    % plot circles
    r = c*d;
    plot(r*cos(0:pi/50:2*pi), r*sin(0:pi/50:2*pi), 'k:');
end

for s=1:S
    % plot lines

    line_len = C*d;
    alpha    = deg2rad(s*g); 

    start_pt = [0, 0];
    end_pt   = start_pt + line_len.*[cos(alpha), sin(alpha)];

    plot([start_pt(1), end_pt(1)], [start_pt(2), end_pt(2)], 'k-');
end

for c=1:C
    % plot centroids of segments
    for s=1:S
        segment_centroid = B_star(c,s, :);
        plot(segment_centroid(1), segment_centroid(2), '.k');
    end
end

% plot some nearest neighbours
% list of [C;S] 
plot_nn = [4;1];

for i = 1:size(plot_nn,2) 
   start_c = plot_nn(1,i);
   start_s = plot_nn(2,i);

   start_pt = [B_star(start_c, start_s,1), B_star(start_c, start_s,2)];
   start_idx = sub2ind([C, S], start_c, start_s);

   plot(start_pt(1), start_pt(2), 'xb');

   nn_idx_list = B_NN{start_idx};

   for j = 1:length(nn_idx_list)
      nn_idx = nn_idx_list(j); 
      [nn_c, nn_s] = ind2sub([C, S], nn_idx);
      nn_pt = [B_star(nn_c, nn_s,1), B_star(nn_c, nn_s,2)];

      plot(nn_pt(1), nn_pt(2), 'xr');
   end
end
```

The full paper can be found [here](http://www.cvc.uab.es/~afornes/publi/journals/2011_SMCB_CBSM.pdf)

Comment: Where in the paper it says which are the nearest neighbors of `b{4,1}`?

Comment: There is a bat in one of the plots.

Comment: In step 2 and illustration (a) `g` being the number of degrees between consecutive sectors should be `360/S` and not `S/360`.

Comment: Have you considered *not* using Euclidean distance, but some other metric? Like keeping your polar coordinates (which are only natural), and using a normalized distance in which 1 angular segment is the same width as 1 radial segment. Or even better: keep the angular*radial discretization as 2d indices [1:n1,1:n2], and identify neighbours as segments for which each index doesn't differ by more than 1 (considering a periodic boundary for the angular variables).

Comment: It seems that what is shown on figure 1D are not the nearest segments, but the neighbouring segments, which is a different thing altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper talks about "region neighbours"; the interpretation that these are the "nearest neighbours" in a Euclidian distance sense is incorrect. They are simply regions that are neighbours of a certain region, and the method of finding them is trivial:

The regions have 2 coordinates: (c,s) where c denotes which concentric circle they're part of, from 1 in the center to C at the edge, and s denotes which sector they're part of, from 1 starting at angle 0° to S ending at angle 360°.

Every region whose c and s coordinates differ at most 1 from the region's coordinates, is a neighbouring region (segment numbers wrap around from S to 1.) Depending on the location of the region, there are 3 cases: *(as illustrated in fig. 1d)*

- **The region is a middle region** (marked MI) e.g. region b(2,4)
  There are 2 neighbouring circles and 2 neighbouring sectors, so 9 regions in total:
  every region in circle 1, 2 or 3 and sector 3, 4 or 5:
  `b(1,3), b(2,3), b(3,3), b(1,4), b(2,4), b(3,4), b(1,5), b(2,5), b(3,5)`
- **The region is an inner region** (marked IN) e.g. region b(1,8)
  There is only one neighbouring circle and 2 neighbouring sectors, but all the inner regions are neighbours, so S + 3 regions in total:
  every region in circle 2 and sector 7, 8 or 1:
  `b(2,7), b(2,8), b(2,1)`
  and every region in the inner circle:
  `b(1,1), b(1,2), b(1,3), b(1,4), b(1,5), b(1,6), b(1,7), b(1,8)`
- **The region is an external region** (marked EX) e.g. region b(3,1)
  There is only one neighbouring circle and 2 neighbouring sectors, so 6 regions in total:
  every region in circle 2 or 3 and sector 8, 1 or 2:
  `b(2,8), b(2,1), b(2,2), b(3,8), b(3,1), b(3,2)`

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit of matlab to the [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33061314/5067311) of @m69, you could automatize the indexing of neighbours like this:

```
%assume C and S defined according to the answer of @m69
iif=@(varargin) varargin{2*find([varargin{1:2:end}], 1, 'first')}();
ncfun=@(c) iif(c==1,c+1,c==C,c-1,true,[c-1, c+1]);
nsfun=@(s)mod([s-1, s+1]-1,S)+1;
neighbs=@(c,s) [b(c,nsfun(s)), b(ncfun(c),s)', reshape(b(ncfun(c),nsfun(s)),1,[])];
```

1. The first one defines [an inline if](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32268411/5067311) for use in anonymous functions, to spare having to define functions in separate files (this would be needed for the `c` case). This has the syntax `iif(condition1,result1,condition2,result2,...)`, where each condition is tested after one another, and the result corresponding to the first condition yielding `true` is returned.
2. The second one defines the radial neighbour indices with an if: return [c-1, c+1] unless either of these is undefined (which would lead to array bound violations)
3. The third one defines a periodic indexing for the angular sectors, such that for `S=4` `nsfun(2)==[1, 3]` and `nsfun(4)==[3, 1]`.
4. I just added an example where for a given valid pair of `c,s` `neighbs(c,s)` will return the subarray of `b(1:C,1:S)` which are neighbours: first the up-down/left-right neighbours, then the (up to) four corner ones.

Comment: Thanks for adding this; I don't know the first thing about Matlab.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I definetly need to dive more into Matlab!

Answer (score 0):

After spending way too many hours on this I figured it out, the trick to calculate the neighboring regions of an element b{c,s} was:

- Take all segments for the neighbouring rings of c, including c itself, i.e  `c-1, c, c+1`, if it's the inner most circle then only `c,c+1` if it's the outer most take `c-1, c`
- Calculate the euclidean distance from b{c,s} to all the selected centroids from the previous step, including the point b{c,s} itself
- Sort the distances in ascending order and take the first N segments.

The descriptor works quite well, however it's rotational invariance depends on the axis with the highest density in certain cases this is very sensitive to noise/occlusion, i.e the descriptor may be +/- 1 rotation off.

Here's the complete CBSM descriptor implementation in MATLAB, not optimized in any way (I heard MATLAB hates for-loops):

**csbm.m**

```
function [descriptor] = csbm(I, R, C, S)
    % Input:
    % ------
    % I = The image, binary, must be square in sice
    % R = The radius of the correlogram, could be half the image width
    % C = Number of circles
    % S = Number of segments per circle

    % Output:
    % -------
    % A C*S-by-1 row vector, the descriptor

    [width, height] = size(I);
    assert(width == height, 'Image must be square in size!');

    % "width" of ring segments
    d = R/C;

    % angle of one segment in degrees
    g = 2*pi/S;

    % centroid coordinates for bins
    B_star = zeros(C*S,2);

    % initialize the descriptor
    descriptor = zeros(C*S,1);

    % calculate centroids of bins
    for c=1:C
        for s=1:S
            alpha = max(s-1, 0)*g + g/2;
            r     = d*max((c-1),0) + d/2;
            ind   = (c-1)*S+s; %sub2ind(cs_size, c,s);

            B_star(ind, :) = [r*cos(alpha), r*sin(alpha)];
        end
    end

    % calculate nearest neighbor regions
    B_NN = cell(C*S,1);

    for c=1:C
        min_circle = max(1,c-1);
        max_circle = min(C,c+1);

        start_sel  = (min_circle-1)*S+1;
        end_sel    = (max_circle)*S;

        centroids  = B_star(start_sel:end_sel, :);

        for s=1:S
            current_ind   = (c-1)*S+s;
            centroid      = B_star(current_ind, :);
            num_centroids = length(centroids);
            distances     = sqrt(sum((centroids-repmat(centroid, num_centroids,1)).^2,2));

            distances     = horzcat(distances, transpose((start_sel:end_sel)));
            distances     = sortrows(distances, [1,2]);

            neighbour_count = 9;

            if c == 1
                % inner region has S+3 neighbours
                neighbour_count = S+3;
            elseif c == C
                % outer most ring has 6 neighbours
                neighbour_count = 6;
            end


            B_NN{current_ind} = distances(1:neighbour_count, 2);
        end
    end

    for x=1:width
        x_centered = x-width/2;

        for y=1:width
            if I(x,y) == 0
                continue;
            end

            y_centered = y-width/2;

            % bin the image point
            r = sqrt(x_centered^2 + y_centered^2);
            a = wrapTo2Pi(atan2(y_centered, x_centered));

            % get bin
            c_pixel = max(1, floor(r/d));
            s_pixel = max(1, floor(a/g));

            if c_pixel > C
                continue;
            end

            ind_pixel = (c_pixel-1)*S+s_pixel;
            pt_pixel  = [x_centered, y_centered];

            % get neighbours of this bin
            neighbours = B_NN{ind_pixel};

            % calculate distance to neighbours
            nn_dists   = sqrt(sum((B_star(neighbours, :) - repmat(pt_pixel, length(neighbours), 1)).^2,2));

            D = sum(1./nn_dists);

            % update the probabilities vector
            descriptor(neighbours) = descriptor(neighbours) + 1./(nn_dists.*D);
        end
    end

    % normalize the vector v
    descriptor   = descriptor./sum(descriptor);

    % make it rotationally invariant
    G = zeros(S/2, 2*C);

    for s=1:S/2
        for c=1:C
            G(s,c)   = descriptor((c-1)*S+s);
            G(s,c+C) = descriptor((c-1)*S+s+S/2);
        end
    end

    [~, max_G_idx] = max(sum(G,2));

    L_G = 0;
    R_G = 0;

    for j=1:C
        for k=1:S
            if k > (max_G_idx) && k < (max_G_idx+S/2)
                L_G = L_G + descriptor((j-1)*S+k); 
            elseif k ~= max_G_idx && k ~= (max_G_idx+S/2)
                R_G = R_G + descriptor((j-1)*S+k); 
            end
        end
    end

    if L_G > R_G
        % B is rotated k=i+S/2-1 positions to the left:
        fprintf('rotate %d to the left\n', max_G_idx+S/2-1);
        rotate_by = -(max_G_idx+S/2-1);
    else
        % B is rotated k=i-1 positions to the right:
        fprintf('rotate %d to the right\n', max_G_idx-1);
        rotate_by = -(max_G_idx-1);
    end

    % segments are grouped by circle
    % so for every circle we get all segments and circular shift them
    for c=1:C
       range_sel = ((c-1)*S+1):(c*S);
       segments  = descriptor(range_sel);
       descriptor(range_sel) = circshift(segments, [rotate_by,0]);
    end
end
```

**plot_descriptor.m**

```
function plot_descriptor(R,C,S, descriptor)
    % Input:
    % ------
    % R Radius for the correlogram in pixels, can be arbitrary
    % C Number of circles
    % S Number of segments per circle
    % descriptor The C*S-by-1 descriptor vector


    % "width" of ring segments
    d = R/C;

    % angle of one segment in degrees
    g = 2*pi/S;

    % full image
    [x,y] = meshgrid(-R:R);
    [theta, rho] = cart2pol(x,y);
    theta = wrapTo2Pi(theta);
    brightness   = zeros(size(rho));

    min_val     = min(descriptor);
    max_val     = max(descriptor);
    scale_fact  = 1/(max_val-min_val);

    for c=1:C
        rInner = (c-1)*d;
        rOuter = c*d;

        for s=1:S
            idx = (c-1)*S+s;

            minTheta = (s-1)*g;
            maxTheta = (s*g);

            matching_theta = find(theta > minTheta & theta < maxTheta);
            matching_rho   = find(rho > rInner & rho < rOuter);
            matching_idx   = intersect(matching_theta, matching_rho);

            intensity = descriptor(idx)*scale_fact;

            brightness(matching_idx) = intensity;
        end
    end

    figure; imshow(mat2gray(brightness));
```

**How to run:**

```
I = imread('bat-18.gif');
I = transpose(im2bw(I, graythresh(I)));
I = edge(I);

[width, height] = size(I);
R = width/2;
C = 24;
S = 24;

descriptor = csbm(I, R, C, S);
plot_descriptor(R,C,S,descriptor);
```

The output:

[image: Bat image example]

Just for the kicks, some scary pictures occured while coding it:

[image]

Comment: `for` loops are not evil in matlab, but often there are better vectorized alternatives. In recent years a `for` loop can be as efficient as a built-in, if used properly. It of course depends on application. You can make other shorthands as well: like drop the `find`s and use logical indexing: `matching_theta = theta > minTheta & theta < maxTheta; matching_rho   = rho > rInner & rho < rOuter; matching_idx   = matching_theta & matching_rho; brightness(matching_idx) = intensity;`.