# Is Ternary operation valid in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, conditional-operator

**Question** is ternary operation valid as i am not able to find any document related to it online. And i also find out that ternary is not possible in **MATLAB** so any suggestion and answers will be appreciated here.

**#Code with ternary operation**

```
taxes = (income > 50000)*(((income-50000) * 0.20)+(0.10*50000)) + (~(income > 50000))*0.10 *50000
#Condition True and this computation False then this computation
```

---

**#Code with if and else**

```
if (income) > 50000
#income = income - 50000
#Taxed at 10% (i.e 0.10) for $ 50000
#taxes = 50000 * 0.10
#Rest income will be Taxed at 20% (i.e 0.20)
taxes = 50000 * 0.10 + ((income-50000) * 0.20)
else
#Taxed at 10% (i.e 0.10)
taxes = income * 0.10
endif
```

Output:

```
GNU Octave, version 6.1.0
Copyright (C) 2020 The Octave Project Developers.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "x86_64-w64-mingw32".

Additional information about Octave is available at https://www.octave.org.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit https://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read https://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.
For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.

>> income = 60000;
>> compute_taxes
taxes = 7000
>> income = 50000;
>> compute_taxes
taxes = 5000
>>
```

Comment: Your "Code with ternary operation" is valid in Octave and MATLAB. It's not a true ternary operator, but it produces equivalent results. The advantage of that code of the `if`/`else` code is that it will work with arrays, not only with scalar values.

Comment: Also, please copy-paste the terminal output into the question, rather than uploading a screen shot. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for reasons.

Comment: I know that it is not but i have tried to replicate it  and i am beginner in Octave but i know python already so i tried this code instead.@CrisLuengo
And yes it is providing me the same functionality

Comment: So what's the question exactly? You seem to already have some code that does what you want?

Comment: @LuisMendo Do we have a ternary operator  in Octave like in python and other language and if yes then what is the syntax of it.

Comment: Maybe write that into the question text to make it clearer. In Octave there is [`merge` or `ifelse`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/merge.html) (they seem to be the same), which is perhaps (similar to) what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few important differences between any definition of a ternary operator in any language, and an if *statement*.

The main one is that the latter is a *statement*, whereas a ternary operator is by definition an *expression*. In other words, you expect it to return a value. An if block in octave/matlab does not "return" a value (i.e. you can't do `a = if ... endif`). If you need something 'returned', you need to assign it to an external variable *inside* the loop, and then use that variable outside the loop.

The second big thing, is that a ternary operator should be *chainable*. Ie you should be able to do "if this, then that, otherwise if that then that other thing", such that at the end of a long chain of comparisons you return a single value.

---

Now, octave and matlab do not have this kind of operator. But in octave, it's easy enough to simulate one, e.g. with cells:

```
M1 = false; M2 = false; M3 = true;
{'expression1', 'expression2', 'expression3', 'fallback'}([ M1, M2, M3, true ]){1}
```

If you really want to, you can make that kind of thing into a nice anonymous function, which returns the first expression for which its mask/test was true:

```
tern = @(varargin) reshape(varargin,2,[])(2,:)([reshape(varargin,2,[]){1,:}]){1}
tern( M1, 1, M2, 2, M3, 3, true, 4 )   % ans = 3
```

where 'fallback' is achieved simply by having a test that evaluates to 'true' explicitly before the 'fallback' value.

<sub>Note: This style of 'chaining' two or more indexing operations inside an anonymous function only works in octave, as unfortunately matlab does not allow chained operations, e.g. `a(1)(2)`. There is nothing stopping you from making an equivalent 'proper', external function though, where you save intermediate results to a temporary variable before indexing it a second time; therefore, conceptually, this strategy will also work in matlab.</sub>

---

Alternatively, you could make a simpler 'ternary operator' (well, function) using a slightly different syntax, where you pass a 'tests/masks' array, and 'expressions', and 'fallback' cells separately. E.g.

```
tern2 = @(M,E,F) [E, F]{find([M, true], 1)}
tern2( [M1, M2, M3], {1, 2, 3}, {4} )   % ans = 3
```

---

Finally, there is also the `ifelse` function, which is similar in spirit, i.e. `ifelse(test, expr_if_true, expr_if_false)`, but this is not really a true ternary operator/function, since it is not chainable; it's more useful for choosing between two alternatives based on a 'true/false mask', e.g.

```
ifelse( [M1, M2, M3], {1, 2, 3}, {4,5,6} )
% ans = { 4, 5, 3 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate ternary `if` operator with two short circuit `&&` and `||` operators.
Consider this `if/else` statement:

```
if condition 
    val = expr1;
else
    val = expr2;
end
```

Define `t` as `t = @(x) 1;` and the ternary `if` operator as:

```
condition && t(val = expr1) || t(val = expr2);
```

An important point in implementing the ternary `if` operator is the evaluation of expressions `expr1` and `expr2`. If `condition` is `true` then `expr2` must not be evaluated and if `condition` is `false` then `expr1` must not be evaluated. In the functions like [`ifelse/merge`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/merge.html) both expressions are evaluated before they are passed to the function so `ifelse` shouldn't be considered as a true ternary `if` operator.

There are some MATLAB based implementations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237198/recursive-anonymous-function-matlab) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310676/is-it-possible-to-have-a-recursive-anonymous-function-in-matlab) that are used to create recursive anonymous function. The trick is that the expressions are wrapped by a lambda to prevent their evaluation.
Consider the following function that computes the nth Fibonacci number:

```
function val = fib(f, n)
  if n <= 2
    val = 1;
  else
    val = f(f, n - 1) + f(f, n - 2));
end
```

The current proposed technique can be used to implement it as (tested on Octave 6.1.0):

```
fib = @(f, n, t = @(x) 1, tmp = n <= 2 && t(val = 1) || t(val = f(f, n - 1) + f(f, n - 2))) val;
```

In situations other than recursive anonymous function you can use this:

```
val = {condition && t(tmp = expr1) || t(tmp = expr2), tmp}{2};
```

However those tricks may not perform better than `if/else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing a ternary conditional operator function

Don't know if the matlab version can handle strings, and arrays as this can

```
clear ternary
function tern = ternary( test, alternatives); 
  if length( alternatives(:,1)) == 1,, alternatives = alternatives(:); end;
  if test,, tern = alternatives(1,:);
  else,     tern = alternatives(2,:); end
return; end;
```

some sample calls

```
methodss =      ['Runge-Kutta';           'Adams-MLS']; 
adaptive_step = ['adaptive step control'; 'fixed step size'];
report_method = @(selectmethod) [char(    ternary    (selectmethod(1), methodss     )) ' ' ...
                                 char(    ternary    (selectmethod(2), adaptive_step))    ];
%
report_method( [true  false]),; % self-starting = true ;   adaptive step size = false
report_method( [false true ]),; % self-starting = false;   adaptive step size = true

% ans = Runge-Kutta fixed step size
% ans = Adams-MLS   adaptive step control

ternary(2 >  2, [123 456]) %  456
ternary(2 >= 2, [123 456]) %  123

ternary(2 >  2, [123 456; 789 999]) %  789   999
ternary(2 >= 2, [123 456; 789 999]) %  123   456
```

Comment: Important point being that ternary( test, alternatives) can be used in anonymous functions  - which was the one big selling point of matlab's

    z = test : x : y;