# Code for iterative function

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vectorization

I'd like to write the Matlab code for the following equation:

```
z(k)=lamda*x(k)+(1-lamda)*z(k-1)
```

`lamda` can be of any value. `x` is a `1000x22` matrix. `Z(0)=0`.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive Anonymous Function Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237198/recursive-anonymous-function-matlab)

Comment: The most important reason why your code doesn't work is because you do not specify a stop condition. See the duplicate for how this can be done.

Comment: The close vote as "too broad" is not justified. it's a low quality question maybe. But if it would be a little more specific, it could be clearly answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iteration function`.same thing like this

```
function z = itrationFunctio(k,x,lambda)
if(k == 0)
    z = 0;
else
    z = lambda*x+(1-lambda)*itrationFunctio((k-1),x,lambda);
end
```

and in your code just call `itrationFunctio(k,x,lambda)`.

Answer (score 0):

Does that vectorized solution work for you?

```
% parameters
x = rand(10,1);
lambda = 2;

% init z, normalize with (1-lambda)
z(2:numel(x)) = lambda/(1-lambda)*x(2:end);

% cumsum, denormalize with (1-lambda)
z = cumsum(z)*(1-lambda)
```

However I don't get why your `x` is a matrix and not a vector. What is `z` supposed to be, in what dimension works `k`? So in case `x`represents a couple of vectors you want to calculate in parallel, that could work:

```
% parameters
x = rand(1000,22);
lambda = 2;

% init z, normalize with (1-lambda)
z(2:size(x,1),:) = lambda/(1-lambda)*x(2:end,:);

% cumsum, denormalize with (1-lambda)
z = cumsum(z,1)*(1-lambda)
```