# How to write an anonymous function with a variable number of output arguments?

Tags: matlab, output, variadic-functions, anonymous-function, function-handle

Using [`deal`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) we can write anonymous functions that have multiple output arguments, like for example

```
minmax = @(x)deal(min(x),max(x));
[u,v] = minmax([1,2,3,4]); % outputs u = 1, v = 4
```

But if you want to provide a function with its gradient to the optimization function [`fminunc`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html) this does not work. <s>The function `fminunc` calls the input function sometimes with one and sometimes with two output arguments.</s> *(EDIT: This is not true, you just have to specify whether you actually want to use the gradient or not, using e.g. `optimset('SpecifyObjectiveGradient',true)`. Then within one call it always asks for the same number of arguments.)*

We have to provide something like

```
function [f,g] = myFun(x)
 f = x^2; % function
 g = 2*x; % gradient
```

which can be called with one *or* two output arguments.

So is there a way to do the same inline without using the `function` keyword?

Comment: Side note: A function similar to your `minmax` was recently (R2017a) added to MATLAB under the name [`bounds`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bounds.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [OP's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48442667/3372061) is good in that it's concise and useful in many cases.

However, it has one main shortcoming, in that it's less scalable than otherwise possible. This claim is made because all functions (`{x^2,2*x,2}`) are evaluated, regardless of whether they're needed as outputs or not - which results in "wasted" computation time and memory consumption when less than 3 outputs are requested.

In the example of this question this is not an issue because the function and its derivatives are very easy to compute and the input `x` is a **scalar**, but under different circumstances, this can be a very real issue.

I'm providing a modified version, which although uglier, avoids the aforementioned problem and is somewhat more general:

```
funcs_to_apply = {@(x)x.^2, @(x)2*x, @(x)2};
unpacker = @(x)deal(x{:});
myFun = @(x)unpacker(cellfun(@(c)feval(c,x),...
                             funcs_to_apply(1:evalin('caller','nargout')),...
                             'UniformOutput',false)...
                    );
```

Notes:

1. The additional functions I use are [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), [`evalin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) and [`feval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html).
2. The `'UniformOutput'` argument was only added so that the output of `cellfun` is a cell (and can be "unpacked" to a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html); we could've wrapped it in `num2cell` instead).
3. The `evalin` trick is required since in the `myFun` scope we don't know how many outputs were requested from `unpacker`.
4. While `eval` in its various forms (here: `evalin`) is usually discouraged, in this case we know exactly who the caller is and that this is a safe operation.

Answer (score 9):

Yes there is, it involves a technique used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237198/recursive-anonymous-function-matlab) about recursive anonymous functions. First we define a helper function

```
helper = @(c,n)deal(c{1:n});
```

which accepts a cell array `c` of the possible outputs as well as an integer `n` that says how many outputs we need. To write our actual function we just need to define the cell array and pass `nargout` (the number of expected output arguments) to `helper`:

```
myFun = @(x)helper({x^2,2*x,2},nargout);
```

This now works perfectly when calling `fminunc`:

```
x = fminunc(myFun,1);
```