# var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}

Tags: javascript, function, methods, syntax

I've recently started maintaining someone else's JavaScript code. I'm fixing bugs, adding features and also trying to tidy up the code and make it more consistent.

The previous developer used two ways of declaring functions and I can't work out if there is a reason behind it or not.

The two ways are:

```
var functionOne = function() {
    // Some code
};
```

And,

```
function functionTwo() {
    // Some code
}
```

What are the reasons for using these two different methods and what are the pros and cons of each? Is there anything that can be done with one method that can't be done with the other?

Answer (score 5593, accepted):

The difference is that `functionOne` is a function expression and so only defined when that line is reached, whereas `functionTwo` is a function declaration and is defined as soon as its surrounding function or script is executed (due to [hoisting](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting.html)).

For example, a function expression:

```js
// TypeError: functionOne is not a function
functionOne();

var functionOne = function() {
  console.log("Hello!");
};
```

And, a function declaration:

```js
// Outputs: "Hello!"
functionTwo();

function functionTwo() {
  console.log("Hello!");
}
```

Historically, function declarations defined within blocks were handled inconsistently between browsers. [Strict mode](https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Glossary/strict_mode) (introduced in ES5) resolved this by scoping function declarations to their enclosing block.

```js
'use strict';    
{ // note this block!
  function functionThree() {
    console.log("Hello!");
  }
}
functionThree(); // ReferenceError
```

Comment: Function definitions are executed when code enters the surrounding block, rather than when it enters the enclosing function.  I don't know if things always worked that way, but it would be unavoidable if a block used `let` or `const` to define a variable that was closed over by a function within it, and applying that rule consistently is probably better than applying it only when unavoidable.

Comment: The sentence "due to hoisting" might give a wrong impression that only the named function gets hoisted. In fact, both `var functionOne` as well as `function functionTwo` get hoisted to some degree - it's just that functionOne is set to undefined (you could call it half-hoisting, variables always get hoisted only to that degree) whereas function functionTwo is fully hoisted in that it's defined and declared. Invoking something that's undefined will of course then throw a typeError.

Comment: There is also a slight variation of `var` case, when one uses `let functionFour = function () {...}`. In this case declaration of `let functionFour` is hoisted. But it does not get initialized, not even with an `undefined` value. So it produces a slightly different error:  _Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'functionFour' before initialization_ The same holds for `const`.

Comment: @rails_has_elegance so what's the point of calling it "half hoisted" if it acts exactly the same as "not hoisted at all"?

Comment: @vanowm it doesn't act the same as "not hoisted at all" though. If it wasn't hoisted you'd get a ReferenceError. Since it's hoisted you get a TypeError.
Compare these two statements in a console:
1. hoisted(); var hoisted = function() {} 2. notHoisted(); const notHoisted = function() {}. In the first case, it's a TypeError because you're trying to invoke undefined (it DID get hoisted though, that's why it's at least undefined, which is still more than nothing at all). In the second case, it's not even undefined, you just get a plain ReferenceError.

Answer (score 2097):

First I want to correct Greg: `function abc(){}` is scoped too — the name `abc` is defined in the scope where this definition is encountered. Example:

```
function xyz(){
  function abc(){};
  // abc is defined here...
}
// ...but not here
```

Secondly, it is possible to combine both styles:

```
var xyz = function abc(){};
```

`xyz` is going to be defined as usual, `abc` is undefined in all browsers but Internet Explorer — do not rely on it being defined. But it will be defined inside its body:

```
var xyz = function abc(){
  // xyz is visible here
  // abc is visible here
}
// xyz is visible here
// abc is undefined here
```

If you want to alias functions on all browsers, use this kind of declaration:

```
function abc(){};
var xyz = abc;
```

In this case, both `xyz` and `abc` are aliases of the same object:

```
console.log(xyz === abc); // prints "true"
```

One compelling reason to use the combined style is the "name" attribute of function objects (**not supported by Internet Explorer**). Basically when you define a function like

```
function abc(){};
console.log(abc.name); // prints "abc"
```

its name is automatically assigned. But when you define it like

```
var abc = function(){};
console.log(abc.name); // prints ""
```

its name is empty — we created an anonymous function and assigned it to some variable.

Another good reason to use the combined style is to use a short internal name to refer to itself, while providing a long non-conflicting name for external users:

```
// Assume really.long.external.scoped is {}
really.long.external.scoped.name = function shortcut(n){
  // Let it call itself recursively:
  shortcut(n - 1);
  // ...
  // Let it pass itself as a callback:
  someFunction(shortcut);
  // ...
}
```

In the example above we can do the same with an external name, but it'll be too unwieldy (and slower).

*(Another way to refer to itself is to use `arguments.callee`, which is still relatively long, and not supported in the strict mode.)*

Deep down, JavaScript treats both statements differently. This is a function declaration:

```
function abc(){}
```

`abc` here is defined everywhere in the current scope:

```
// We can call it here
abc(); // Works

// Yet, it is defined down there.
function abc(){}

// We can call it again
abc(); // Works
```

Also, it hoisted through a `return` statement:

```
// We can call it here
abc(); // Works
return;
function abc(){}
```

This is a function expression:

```
var xyz = function(){};
```

`xyz` here is defined from the point of assignment:

```
// We can't call it here
xyz(); // UNDEFINED!!!

// Now it is defined
xyz = function(){}

// We can call it here
xyz(); // works
```

Function declaration vs. function expression is the real reason why there is a difference demonstrated by Greg.

Fun fact:

```
var xyz = function abc(){};
console.log(xyz.name); // Prints "abc"
```

Personally, I prefer the "function expression" declaration because this way I can control the visibility. When I define the function like

```
var abc = function(){};
```

I know that I defined the function locally. When I define the function like

```
abc = function(){};
```

I know that I defined it globally providing that I didn't define `abc` anywhere in the chain of scopes. This style of definition is resilient even when used inside `eval()`. While the definition

```
function abc(){};
```

depends on the context and may leave you guessing where it is actually defined, especially in the case of `eval()` — the answer is: It depends on the browser.

Comment: var abc = function(){};
console.log(abc.name); // "abc" // from 2021

Comment: Apparently, the JS runtime became smarter. Yet wrap it up and:
var abc = (() => function(){})(); console.log(abc.name); // nothing

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin you are executing the function and trying to read the name of the result. Remove the '();' part  and yours example will e correct ;)

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin you are defining a function and immediately invoking (calling) it, also called an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), which is one method of implementing lexical scoping (nothing from inside the IIFE will be accessible outside of it). So the value of `abc` is not the function itself but rather that function's return value. It makes sense for abc.name to be empty, because abc returns an unnamed function. @ikirachen mentioned removing the `()` because that is what is invoking the function. Without that, it's just wrapped in superfluous parentheses.

Comment: To be clear, it's a way to implement tighter scoping in that variables declared within those parentheses using `var` will be function-scoped as usual, but that anonymous function is no longer accessible outside of the parentheses it's wrapped in. Thankfully these days we have `let`, which uses the block scoping the average (sane) person would expect. It's best to pretend `var` doesn't exist, in my opinion.

Comment: @EugeneLazutkin var abc = (() => function(){})();

Comment: I see. It is in a comment, not in the answer. The comment was about a fact that in some cases a modern JS interpreter can “deduce” a function name, but not in all cases. The comment before that gave an example, which didn’t work, when I wrote the answer, yet started to work in some JS interpreters. The point of my comment was that “var abc = expr” does not name a functional value “abc” in usual cases. It is a confusing shortcut implemented by implementers apparently to help debugging. Are we good now?

Answer (score 742):

Here's the rundown on the standard forms that create functions: *(Originally written for another question, but adapted after being moved into the canonical question.)*

Terms:

- **ES5**: [ECMAScript 5th edition](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), 2009
- **ES2015**: [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) (also known as "ES6")

The quick list:

- Function Declaration
- "Anonymous" `function` Expression *(which despite the term, sometimes create functions with names)*
- Named `function` Expression
- Accessor Function Initializer (ES5+)
- Arrow Function Expression (ES2015+) *(which, like anonymous function expressions, don't involve an explicit name, and yet can create functions with names)*
- Method Declaration in Object Initializer (ES2015+)
- Constructor and Method Declarations in `class` (ES2015+)

#### Function Declaration

The first form is a *function declaration*, which looks like this:

```
function x() {
    console.log('x');
}
```

A function declaration is a *declaration*; it's not a statement or expression. As such, you don't follow it with a `;` (although doing so is harmless).

A function declaration is processed when execution enters the context in which it appears, **before** any step-by-step code is executed. The function it creates is given a proper name (`x` in the example above), and that name is put in the scope in which the declaration appears.

Because it's processed before any step-by-step code in the same context, you can do things like this:

```
x(); // Works even though it's above the declaration
function x() {
    console.log('x');
}
```

Until ES2015, the spec didn't cover what a JavaScript engine should do if you put a function declaration inside a control structure like `try`, `if`, `switch`, `while`, etc., like this:

```
if (someCondition) {
    function foo() {    // <===== HERE THERE
    }                   // <===== BE DRAGONS
}
```

And since they're processed *before* step-by-step code is run, it's tricky to know what to do when they're in a control structure.

Although doing this wasn't *specified* until ES2015, it was an *allowable extension* to support function declarations in blocks. Unfortunately (and inevitably), different engines did different things.

As of ES2015, the specification says what to do. In fact, it gives three separate things to do:

1. If in loose mode *not* on a web browser, the JavaScript engine is supposed to do one thing
2. If in loose mode on a web browser, the JavaScript engine is supposed to do something else
3. If in *strict* mode (browser or not), the JavaScript engine is supposed to do yet another thing

The rules for the loose modes are tricky, but in *strict* mode, function declarations in blocks are easy: They're local to the block (they have *block scope*, which is also new in ES2015), and they're hoisted to the top of the block. So:

```
"use strict";
if (someCondition) {
    foo();               // Works just fine
    function foo() {
    }
}
console.log(typeof foo); // "undefined" (`foo` is not in scope here
                         // because it's not in the same block)
```

#### "Anonymous" `function` Expression

The second common form is called an *anonymous function expression*:

```
var y = function () {
    console.log('y');
};
```

Like all expressions, it's evaluated when it's reached in the step-by-step execution of the code.

In ES5, the function this creates has no name (it's anonymous). In ES2015, the function is assigned a name if possible by inferring it from context. In the example above, the name would be `y`. Something similar is done when the function is the value of a property initializer. (For details on when this happens and the rules, search for `SetFunctionName` in the [the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) — it appears *all over* the place.)

#### Named `function` Expression

The third form is a *named function expression* ("NFE"):

```
var z = function w() {
    console.log('zw')
};
```

The function this creates has a proper name (`w` in this case). Like all expressions, this is evaluated when it's reached in the step-by-step execution of the code. The name of the function is *not* added to the scope in which the expression appears; the name *is* in scope within the function itself:

```
var z = function w() {
    console.log(typeof w); // "function"
};
console.log(typeof w);     // "undefined"
```

Note that NFEs have frequently been a source of bugs for JavaScript implementations. IE8 and earlier, for instance, handle NFEs [completely incorrectly](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html), creating two different functions at two different times. Early versions of Safari had issues as well. The good news is that current versions of browsers (IE9 and up, current Safari) don't have those issues any more. (But as of this writing, sadly, IE8 remains in widespread use, and so using NFEs with code for the web in general is still problematic.)

#### Accessor Function Initializer (ES5+)

Sometimes functions can sneak in largely unnoticed; that's the case with *accessor functions*. Here's an example:

```
var obj = {
    value: 0,
    get f() {
        return this.value;
    },
    set f(v) {
        this.value = v;
    }
};
console.log(obj.f);         // 0
console.log(typeof obj.f);  // "number"
```

Note that when I used the function, I didn't use `()`! That's because it's an *accessor function* for a property. We get and set the property in the normal way, but behind the scenes, the function is called.

You can also create accessor functions with `Object.defineProperty`, `Object.defineProperties`, and the lesser-known second argument to `Object.create`.

#### Arrow Function Expression (ES2015+)

ES2015 brings us the *arrow function*. Here's one example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = a.map(n => n * 2);
console.log(b.join(", ")); // 2, 4, 6
```

See that `n => n * 2` thing hiding in the `map()` call? That's a function.

A couple of things about arrow functions:

1. They don't have their own `this`. Instead, they *close over* the `this` of the context where they're defined. (They also close over `arguments` and, where relevant, `super`.) This means that the `this` within them is the same as the `this` where they're created, and cannot be changed.
2. As you'll have noticed with the above, you don't use the keyword `function`; instead, you use `=>`.

The `n => n * 2` example above is one form of them. If you have multiple arguments to pass the function, you use parens:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = a.map((n, i) => n * i);
console.log(b.join(", ")); // 0, 2, 6
```

(Remember that `Array#map` passes the entry as the first argument, and the index as the second.)

In both cases, the body of the function is just an expression; the function's return value will automatically be the result of that expression (you don't use an explicit `return`).

If you're doing more than just a single expression, use `{}` and an explicit `return` (if you need to return a value), as normal:

```
var a = [
  {first: "Joe", last: "Bloggs"},
  {first: "Albert", last: "Bloggs"},
  {first: "Mary", last: "Albright"}
];
a = a.sort((a, b) => {
  var rv = a.last.localeCompare(b.last);
  if (rv === 0) {
    rv = a.first.localeCompare(b.first);
  }
  return rv;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

The version without `{ ... }` is called an arrow function with an *expression body* or *concise body*. (Also: A *concise* arrow function.) The one with `{ ... }` defining the body is an arrow function with a *function body*. (Also: A *verbose* arrow function.)

#### Method Declaration in Object Initializer (ES2015+)

ES2015 allows a shorter form of declaring a property that references a function called a *method definition*; it looks like this:

```
var o = {
    foo() {
    }
};
```

the almost-equivalent in ES5 and earlier would be:

```
var o = {
    foo: function foo() {
    }
};
```

the difference (other than verbosity) is that a method can use `super`, but a function cannot. So for instance, if you had an object that defined (say) `valueOf` using method syntax, it could use `super.valueOf()` to get the value `Object.prototype.valueOf` would have returned (before presumably doing something else with it), whereas the ES5 version would have to do `Object.prototype.valueOf.call(this)` instead.

That also means that the method has a reference to the object it was defined on, so if that object is temporary (for instance, you're passing it into `Object.assign` as one of the source objects), method syntax *could* mean that the object is retained in memory when otherwise it could have been garbage collected (if the JavaScript engine doesn't detect that situation and handle it if none of the methods uses `super`).

#### Constructor and Method Declarations in `class` (ES2015+)

ES2015 brings us `class` syntax, including declared constructors and methods:

```
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    getFullName() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

There are two function declarations above: One for the constructor, which gets the name `Person`, and one for `getFullName`, which is a function assigned to `Person.prototype`.

Answer (score 175):

Speaking about the global context, both, the `var` statement and a `FunctionDeclaration` at the end will create a *non-deleteable* property on the global object, but the value of both *can be overwritten*.

The subtle difference between the two ways is that when the [Variable Instantiation](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.3) process runs (before the actual code execution) all identifiers declared with `var` will be initialized with `undefined`, and the ones used by the `FunctionDeclaration`'s will be available since that moment, for example:

```
 alert(typeof foo); // 'function', it's already available
 alert(typeof bar); // 'undefined'
 function foo () {}
 var bar = function () {};
 alert(typeof bar); // 'function'
```

The assignment of the `bar` `FunctionExpression` takes place until runtime.

A global property created by a `FunctionDeclaration` can be overwritten without any problems just like a variable value, e.g.:

```
 function test () {}
 test = null;
```

Another obvious difference between your two examples is that the first function doesn't have a name, but the second has it, which can be really useful when debugging (i.e. inspecting a call stack).

About your edited first example (`foo = function() { alert('hello!'); };`), it is an undeclared assignment, I would highly encourage you to always use the `var` keyword.

With an assignment, without the `var` statement, if the referenced identifier is not found in the scope chain, it will become a *deleteable* property of the global object.

Also, undeclared assignments throw a `ReferenceError` on ECMAScript 5 under [Strict Mode](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-2-strict-mode/).

A must read:

- [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

**Note**: This answer has been merged from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435709/why-are-functions-in-javascript-set-to-global-variables-instead-of-plain-function), in which the major doubt and misconception from the OP was that identifiers declared with a `FunctionDeclaration`, couldn't be overwritten which is not the case.

Answer (score 146):

The two code snippets you've posted there will, for almost all purposes, behave the same way.

However, the difference in behaviour is that with the first variant (`var functionOne = function() {}`), that function can only be called after that point in the code.

With the second variant (`function functionTwo()`), the function is available to code that runs above where the function is declared.

This is because with the first variant, the function is assigned to the variable `foo` at run time. In the second, the function is assigned to that identifier, `foo`, at parse time.

**More technical information**

JavaScript has three ways of defining functions.

1. Your first snippet shows a **function expression**. This involves using the *"function" operator* to create a function - the result of that operator can be stored in any variable or object property. The function expression is powerful that way. The function expression is often called an "anonymous function", because it does not have to have a name,
2. Your second example is a **function declaration**. This uses the *"function" statement* to create a function. The function is made available at parse time and can be called anywhere in that scope. You can still store it in a variable or object property later.
3. The third way of defining a function is the **"Function()" constructor**, which is not shown in your original post. It's not recommended to use this as it works the same way as `eval()`, which has its problems.

Answer (score 126):

A better explanation to [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/2351696)

```
functionTwo();
function functionTwo() {
}
```

**Why no error? We were always taught that expressions are executed from top to bottom(??)**

### Because:

> Function declarations and variable declarations are always moved (`hoisted`) invisibly to the top of their containing scope by the JavaScript interpreter. Function parameters and language-defined names are, obviously, already there. [ben cherry](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)

This means that code like this:

```
functionOne();                  ---------------      var functionOne;
                                | is actually |      functionOne();
var functionOne = function(){   | interpreted |-->
};                              |    like     |      functionOne = function(){
                                ---------------      };
```

Notice that the assignment portion of the declarations were not hoisted. Only the name is hoisted.

*But in the case with function declarations, the entire function body will be hoisted as well*:

```
functionTwo();              ---------------      function functionTwo() {
                            | is actually |      };
function functionTwo() {    | interpreted |-->
}                           |    like     |      functionTwo();
                            ---------------
```

Answer (score 107):

Other commenters have already covered the semantic difference of the two variants above. I wanted to note a stylistic difference: Only the "assignment" variation can set a property of another object.

I often build JavaScript modules with a pattern like this:

```
(function(){
    var exports = {};

    function privateUtil() {
            ...
    }

    exports.publicUtil = function() {
            ...
    };

    return exports;
})();
```

With this pattern, your public functions will all use assignment, while your private functions use declaration.

(Note also that assignment should require a semicolon after the statement, while declaration prohibits it.)

Answer (score 91):

An illustration of when to prefer the first method to the second one is when you need to avoid overriding a function's previous definitions.

With

```
if (condition){
    function myfunction(){
        // Some code
    }
}
```

, this definition of `myfunction` will override any previous definition, since it will be done at parse-time.

While

```
if (condition){
    var myfunction = function (){
        // Some code
    }
}
```

does the correct job of defining `myfunction` only when `condition` is met.

Answer (score 72):

An important reason is to add one and only one variable as the "Root" of your namespace...

```
var MyNamespace = {}
MyNamespace.foo= function() {

}
```

or

```
var MyNamespace = {
  foo: function() {
  },
  ...
}
```

There are many techniques for namespacing. It's become more important with the plethora of JavaScript modules available.

Also see *[How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/)*

Answer (score 64):

**[Hoisting](http://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-hoisting/)** *is the JavaScript interpreter’s action of moving all variable and function declarations to the top of the current scope.*

*However, only the actual declarations are hoisted. by leaving assignments where they are.*

- variable's/Function's declared inside the page are global can access anywhere in that page.
- variable's/Functions declared inside the function are having local scope. means they are available/accessed inside the function body (scope), they are not available outside the function body.

**[Variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables)**

*Javascript is called loosely typed language. Which means Javascript variables can hold value of any [Data-Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx). Javascript automatically takes care of changing the variable-type based on the value/literal provided during runtime.*

```
global_Page = 10;                                               var global_Page;      « undefined
    « Integer literal, Number Type.   -------------------       global_Page = 10;     « Number         
global_Page = 'Yash';                 |   Interpreted   |       global_Page = 'Yash'; « String
    « String literal, String Type.    «       AS        «       global_Page = true;   « Boolean 
var global_Page = true;               |                 |       global_Page = function (){          « function
    « Boolean Type                    -------------------                 var local_functionblock;  « undefined
global_Page = function (){                                                local_functionblock = 777;« Number
    var local_functionblock = 777;                              };  
    // Assigning function as a data.
};
```

---

**Function**

```
function Identifier_opt ( FormalParameterList_opt ) { 
      FunctionBody | sequence of statements

      « return;  Default undefined
      « return 'some data';
}
```

- functions declared inside the page are hoisted to top of the page having global access.
- functions declared inside the function-block are hoisted to top of the block.
- Default return value of function is '[undefined](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/)', [Variable](http://javascript.info/tutorial/variables-and-statements) declaration default value also 'undefined'

  ```
  Scope with respect to function-block global. 
  Scope with respect to page undefined | not available.
  ```

**Function Declaration**

```
function globalAccess() {                                  function globalAccess() {      
}                                  -------------------     }
globalAccess();                    |                 |     function globalAccess() { « Re-Defined / overridden.
localAccess();                     «   Hoisted  As   «         function localAccess() {
function globalAccess() {          |                 |         }
     localAccess();                -------------------         localAccess(); « function accessed with in globalAccess() only.
     function localAccess() {                              }
     }                                                     globalAccess();
}                                                          localAccess(); « ReferenceError as the function is not defined
```

**Function Expression**

```
        10;                 « literal
       (10);                « Expression                (10).toString() -> '10'
var a;                      
    a = 10;                 « Expression var              a.toString()  -> '10'
(function invoke() {        « Expression Function
 console.log('Self Invoking');                      (function () {
});                                                               }) () -> 'Self Invoking'

var f; 
    f = function (){        « Expression var Function
    console.log('var Function');                                   f ()  -> 'var Function'
    };
```

*Function assigned to variable Example:*

```
(function selfExecuting(){
    console.log('IIFE - Immediately-Invoked Function Expression');
}());

var anonymous = function (){
    console.log('anonymous function Expression');
};

var namedExpression = function for_InternalUSE(fact){
    if(fact === 1){
        return 1;
    }

    var localExpression = function(){
        console.log('Local to the parent Function Scope');
    };
    globalExpression = function(){ 
        console.log('creates a new global variable, then assigned this function.');
    };

    //return; //undefined.
    return fact * for_InternalUSE( fact - 1);   
};

namedExpression();
globalExpression();
```

javascript interpreted as

```
var anonymous;
var namedExpression;
var globalExpression;

anonymous = function (){
    console.log('anonymous function Expression');
};

namedExpression = function for_InternalUSE(fact){
    var localExpression;

    if(fact === 1){
        return 1;
    }
    localExpression = function(){
        console.log('Local to the parent Function Scope');
    };
    globalExpression = function(){ 
        console.log('creates a new global variable, then assigned this function.');
    };

    return fact * for_InternalUSE( fact - 1);    // DEFAULT UNDEFINED.
};

namedExpression(10);
globalExpression();
```

You can check function declaration, expression test over different browser's using [`jsperf Test Runner`](http://jsperf.com/yashfunctions)

---

**[ES5 Constructor Function Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45759444/5081877): Function objects created using Function.prototype.bind**

JavaScript treats functions as first-class objects, so being an object, you can assign properties to a function.

```
function Shape(id) { // Function Declaration
    this.id = id;
};
    // Adding a prototyped method to a function.
    Shape.prototype.getID = function () {
        return this.id;
    };
    Shape.prototype.setID = function ( id ) {
        this.id = id;
    };

var expFn = Shape; // Function Expression

var funObj = new Shape( ); // Function Object
funObj.hasOwnProperty('prototype'); // false
funObj.setID( 10 );
console.log( funObj.getID() ); // 10
```

---

ES6 introduced **Arrow function**: An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax, they are best suited for non-method functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

> [`ArrowFunction : ArrowParameters => ConciseBody`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors).
>
> ```
> const fn = (item) => { return item & 1 ? 'Odd' : 'Even'; };
> console.log( fn(2) ); // Even
> console.log( fn(3) ); // Odd
> ```

Answer (score 53):

## .

1. Availability (scope) of the function

The following works because `function add()` is scoped to the nearest block:

```js
try {
  console.log("Success: ", add(1, 1));
} catch(e) {
  console.log("ERROR: " + e);
}

function add(a, b){
  return a + b;
}
```

The following does not work because the variable is called before a function value is assigned to the variable `add`.

```js
try {
  console.log("Success: ", add(1, 1));
} catch(e) {
  console.log("ERROR: " + e);
}

var add=function(a, b){
  return a + b;
}
```

The above code is identical in functionality to the code below. Note that explicitly assigning `add = undefined` is superfluous because simply doing `var add;` is the exact same as `var add=undefined`.

```js
var add = undefined;

try {
  console.log("Success: ", add(1, 1));
} catch(e) {
  console.log("ERROR: " + e);
}

add = function(a, b){
  return a + b;
}
```

The following does not work because `var add=` begins an expression and causes the following `function add()` to be an expression instead of a block. Named functions are only visible to themselves and their surrounding block. As `function add()` is an expression here, it has no surrounding block, so it is only visible to itself.

```js
try {
  console.log("Success: ", add(1, 1));
} catch(e) {
  console.log("ERROR: " + e);
}

var add=function add(a, b){
  return a + b;
}
```

2. *(function)*.name

The name of a function `function thefuncname(){}` is *thefuncname* when it is declared this way.

```js
function foobar(a, b){}

console.log(foobar.name);
```

```js
var a = function foobar(){};

console.log(a.name);
```

Otherwise, if a function is declared as `function(){}`, the *function*.name is the first variable used to store the function.

```js
var a = function(){};
var b = (function(){ return function(){} });

console.log(a.name);
console.log(b.name);
```

If there are no variables set to the function, then the functions name is the empty string (`""`).

```js
console.log((function(){}).name === "");
```

Lastly, while the variable the function is assigned to initially sets the name, successive variables set to the function do not change the name.

```js
var a = function(){};
var b = a;
var c = b;

console.log(a.name);
console.log(b.name);
console.log(c.name);
```

3. Performance

In Google's V8 and Firefox's Spidermonkey there might be a few microsecond JIT compilation difference, but ultimately the result is the exact same. To prove this, let's examine the efficiency of JSPerf at micro-benchmarks by comparing the speed of two blank code snippets. The [JSPerf tests are found here](https://jsperf.com/microbenchmark-analysis/1). And, the [jsben.ch tests are  found here](http://jsben.ch/Ov6eJ). As you can see, there is a noticeable difference when there should be none. If you are really a performance freak like me, then it might be more worth your while trying to reduce the number of variables and functions in the scope and especially eliminating polymorphism (such as using the same variable to store two different types).

4. Variable Mutability

When you use the `var` keyword to declare a variable, you can then reassign a different value to the variable like so.

```js
(function(){
    "use strict";
    var foobar = function(){}; // initial value
    try {
        foobar = "Hello World!"; // new value
        console.log("[no error]");
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error.message);
    }
    console.log(foobar, window.foobar);
})();
```

However, when we use the const-statement, the variable reference becomes immutable. This means that we cannot assign a new value to the variable. Please note, however, that this does not make the contents of the variable immutable: if you do `const arr = []`, then you can still do `arr[10] = "example"`. Only doing something like `arr = "new value"` or `arr = []` would throw an error as seen below.

```js
(function(){
    "use strict";
    const foobar = function(){}; // initial value
    try {
        foobar = "Hello World!"; // new value
        console.log("[no error]");
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error.message);
    }
    console.log(foobar, window.foobar);
})();
```

Interestingly, if we declare the variable as `function funcName(){}`, then the immutability of the variable is the same as declaring it with `var`.

```js
(function(){
    "use strict";
    function foobar(){}; // initial value
    try {
        foobar = "Hello World!"; // new value
        console.log("[no error]");
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error.message);
    }
    console.log(foobar, window.foobar);
})();
```

### " "

The "nearest block" is the nearest "function," (including asynchronous functions, generator functions, and asynchronous generator functions). However, interestingly, a `function functionName() {}` behaves like a `var functionName = function() {}` when in a non-closure block to items outside said closure. Observe.

- Normal `var add=function(){}`

```js
try {
  // typeof will simply return "undefined" if the variable does not exist
  if (typeof add !== "undefined") {
    add(1, 1); // just to prove it
    console.log("Not a block");
  }else if(add===undefined){ // this throws an exception if add doesn't exist
    console.log('Behaves like var add=function(a,b){return a+b}');
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Is a block");
}
var add=function(a, b){return a + b}
```

- Normal `function add(){}`

```js
try {
  // typeof will simply return "undefined" if the variable does not exist
  if (typeof add !== "undefined") {
    add(1, 1); // just to prove it
    console.log("Not a block");
  }else if(add===undefined){ // this throws an exception if add doesn't exist
    console.log('Behaves like var add=function(a,b){return a+b}')
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Is a block");
}
function add(a, b){
  return a + b;
}
```

- Function

```js
try {
  // typeof will simply return "undefined" if the variable does not exist
  if (typeof add !== "undefined") {
    add(1, 1); // just to prove it
    console.log("Not a block");
  }else if(add===undefined){ // this throws an exception if add doesn't exist
    console.log('Behaves like var add=function(a,b){return a+b}')
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Is a block");
}
(function () {
    function add(a, b){
      return a + b;
    }
})();
```

- Statement (such as `if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, `try`/`catch`/`finally`, `switch`, `do`/`while`, `with`)

```js
try {
  // typeof will simply return "undefined" if the variable does not exist
  if (typeof add !== "undefined") {
    add(1, 1); // just to prove it
    console.log("Not a block");
  }else if(add===undefined){ // this throws an exception if add doesn't exist
    console.log('Behaves like var add=function(a,b){return a+b}')
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Is a block");
}
{
    function add(a, b){
      return a + b;
    }
}
```

- Arrow Function with `var add=function()`

```js
try {
  // typeof will simply return "undefined" if the variable does not exist
  if (typeof add !== "undefined") {
    add(1, 1); // just to prove it
    console.log("Not a block");
  }else if(add===undefined){ // this throws an exception if add doesn't exist
    console.log('Behaves like var add=function(a,b){return a+b}')
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Is a block");
}
(() => {
    var add=function(a, b){
      return a + b;
    }
})();
```

- Arrow Function With `function add()`

```js
try {
  // typeof will simply return "undefined" if the variable does not exist
  if (typeof add !== "undefined") {
    add(1, 1); // just to prove it
    console.log("Not a block");
  }else if(add===undefined){ // this throws an exception if add doesn't exist
    console.log('Behaves like var add=function(a,b){return a+b}')
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Is a block");
}
(() => {
    function add(a, b){
      return a + b;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 50):

I'm adding my own answer just because everyone else has covered the hoisting part thoroughly.

I've wondered about which way is better for a long while now, and thanks to http://jsperf.com now I know :)

[image]

**Function declarations** are faster, and that's what really matters in web dev right? ;)

Comment: see [answer about performance below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46461041), different results

Answer (score 41):

A function declaration and a function expression assigned to a variable behave the same once the binding is established.

There is a difference however at *how* and *when* the function object is actually associated with its variable. This difference is due to the mechanism called *variable hoisting* in JavaScript.

Basically, all function declarations and variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the *function* in which the declaration occurs (this is why we say that JavaScript has *function scope*).

- When a function declaration is hoisted, the function body "follows"
  so when the function body is evaluated, the variable will immediately
  be bound to a function object.
- When a variable declaration is hoisted, the initialization does *not*
  follow, but is "left behind". The variable is initialized to
  `undefined` at the start of the function body, and will be *assigned*
  a value at its original location in the code. (Actually, it will be assigned a value at *every* location where a declaration of a variable with the same name occurs.)

The order of hoisting is also important: function declarations take precedence over variable declarations with the same name, and the last function declaration takes precedence over previous function declarations with the same name.

Some examples...

```
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
  if (!foo) {
    var foo = 10 }
  return foo; }
bar() // 10
```

Variable `foo` is hoisted to the top of the function, initialized to `undefined`, so that `!foo` is `true`, so `foo` is assigned `10`. The `foo` outside of `bar`'s scope plays no role and is untouched.

```
function f() {
  return a; 
  function a() {return 1}; 
  var a = 4;
  function a() {return 2}}
f()() // 2

function f() {
  return a;
  var a = 4;
  function a() {return 1};
  function a() {return 2}}
f()() // 2
```

Function declarations take precedence over variable declarations, and the last function declaration "sticks".

```
function f() {
  var a = 4;
  function a() {return 1}; 
  function a() {return 2}; 
  return a; }
f() // 4
```

In this example `a` is initialized with the function object resulting from evaluating the second function declaration, and then is assigned `4`.

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
  a = 10;
  return;
  function a() {}}
b();
a // 1
```

Here the function declaration is hoisted first, declaring and initializing variable `a`. Next, this variable is assigned `10`. In other words: the assignment does not assign to outer variable `a`.

Answer (score 38):

The first example is a function declaration:

```
function abc(){}
```

The second example is a function expression:

```
var abc = function() {};
```

The main difference is how they are hoisted (lifted and declared). In the first example, the whole function declaration is hoisted. In the second example only the var 'abc' is hoisted, its value (the function) will be undefined, and the function itself remains at the position that it is declared.

To put it simply:

```
//this will work
abc(param);
function abc(){}

//this would fail
abc(param);
var abc = function() {}
```

To study more about this topic I strongly recommend you this
[link](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/#comment-43792)

Answer (score 37):

In terms of code maintenance cost, named functions are more preferable:

- Independent from the place where they are declared (but still limited by scope).
- More resistant to mistakes like conditional initialization (you are still able to override if wanted to).
- The code becomes more readable by allocating local functions separately of scope functionality. Usually in the scope the functionality goes first, followed by declarations of local functions.
- In a debugger you will clearly see the function name on the call stack instead of an "anonymous/evaluated" function.

I suspect more PROS for named functions are follow. And what is listed as an advantage of named functions is a disadvantage for anonymous ones.

Historically, anonymous functions appeared from the inability of JavaScript as a language to list members with named functions:

```
{
    member:function() { /* How do I make "this.member" a named function? */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 33):

In computer science terms, we talk about anonymous functions and named functions. I think the most important difference is that an anonymous function is not bound to a name, hence the name anonymous function. In JavaScript it is a first class object dynamically declared at runtime.

For more information on anonymous functions and lambda calculus, Wikipedia is a good start: [Anonymous Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).

Answer (score 33):

[Greg's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336868/2730064) is good enough, but I still would like to add something to it that I learned just now watching [Douglas Crockford's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) videos.

**Function expression:**

```
var foo = function foo() {};
```

**Function statement:**

```
function foo() {};
```

The function statement is just a shorthand for `var` statement with a `function` value.

So

```
function foo() {};
```

expands to

```
var foo = function foo() {};
```

Which expands further to:

```
var foo = undefined;
foo = function foo() {};
```

And they are both hoisted to the top of the code.

[image: Screenshot from video]

Answer (score 32):

I use the variable approach in my code for a very specific reason, the theory of which has been covered in an abstract way above, but an example might help some people like me, with limited JavaScript expertise.

I have code that I need to run with 160 independently-designed brandings. Most of the code is in shared files, but branding-specific stuff is in a separate file, one for each branding.

Some brandings require specific functions, and some do not. Sometimes I have to add new functions to do new branding-specific things. I am happy to change the shared coded, but I don't want to have to change all 160 sets of branding files.

By using the variable syntax, I can declare the variable (a function pointer essentially) in the shared code and either assign a trivial stub function, or set to null.

The one or two brandings that need a specific implementation of the function can then define their version of the function and assign this to the variable if they want, and the rest do nothing. I can test for a null function before I execute it in the shared code.

From people's comments above, I gather it may be possible to redefine a static function too, but I think the variable solution is nice and clear.

Answer (score 26):

[@EugeneLazutkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26394/eugene-lazutkin) gives an example where he [names an assigned function to be able to use `shortcut()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338053/) as an internal reference to itself. [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/) gives another example - *copying a recursive function assigned to another object* in his [Learning Advanced Javascript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) tutorial. While assigning functions to properties isn't strictly the question here, I recommend actively trying the tutorial out - run the code by clicking the button in the upper right corner, and double click the code to edit to your liking.

Examples from the tutorial: recursive calls in `yell()`:

[Tests fail when the original ninja object is removed.](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#13) (page 13)

```js
function assert(predicate, message) { if(!predicate) { throw new Error(message); } }

var ninja = {
  yell: function(n){
return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
  }
};
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "A single object isn't too bad, either." ); 

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
var ninja = null;

try {
  samurai.yell(4);
} catch(e){
  assert( false, "Uh, this isn't good! Where'd ninja.yell go?" );
}
```

[If you name the function that will be called recursively, the tests will pass.](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#14) (page 14)

```js
function assert(predicate, message) { if(!predicate) { throw new Error(message); } }

var ninja = {
  yell: function yell(n){
return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
  }
};
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "Works as we would expect it to!" );
 
var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
var ninja = {};
assert( samurai.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "The method correctly calls itself." );

console.log(samurai.yell(4));
```

Answer (score 21):

Another difference that is not mentioned in the other answers is that if you use the anonymous function and use that as a constructor as in

```js
var functionOne = function() {
    // Some code
};

var one = new functionOne();

console.log(one.constructor.name);
```

then `one.constructor.name` will not be defined. `Function.name` is non-standard but is supported by Firefox, Chrome, other Webkit-derived browsers and IE 9+.

With

```
function functionTwo() {
    // Some code
}
two = new functionTwo();
```

it is possible to retrieve the name of the constructor as a string with `two.constructor.name`.

Answer (score 20):

The first one (function doSomething(x)) should be part of an object notation.

The second one (`var doSomething = function(x){ alert(x);}`) is simply creating an anonymous function and assigning it to a variable, `doSomething`. So doSomething() will call the function.

You may want to know what a *function declaration* and *function expression* is.

A function declaration defines a named function variable without requiring variable assignment. Function declarations occur as standalone constructs and cannot be nested within non-function blocks.

```
function foo() {
    return 3;
}
```

> ECMA 5 (13.0) defines the syntax as 
>   function Identifier ( FormalParameterList<sub>opt</sub> ) { FunctionBody }

In above condition the function name is visible within its scope and the scope of its parent (otherwise it would be unreachable).

And in a function expression

A function expression defines a function as a part of a larger expression syntax (typically a variable assignment ). Functions defined via functions expressions can be named or anonymous. Function expressions should not start with “function”.

```
// Anonymous function expression
var a = function() {
    return 3;
}

// Named function expression
var a = function foo() {
    return 3;
}

// Self-invoking function expression
(function foo() {
    alert("hello!");
})();
```

> ECMA 5 (13.0) defines the syntax as 
>   function Identifier<sub>opt</sub> ( FormalParameterList<sub>opt</sub> ) { FunctionBody }

Answer (score 19):

I'm listing out the differences below:

1. A function declaration can be placed anywhere in the code. Even if it is invoked before the definition appears in code, it gets executed as function declaration is committed to memory or in a way it is hoisted up, before any other code in the page starts execution.

   Take a look at the function below:

   ```
   function outerFunction() {
       function foo() {
          return 1;
       }
       return foo();
       function foo() {
          return 2;
       }
   }
   alert(outerFunction()); // Displays 2
   ```

   This is because, during execution, it looks like:-

   ```
   function foo() {  // The first function declaration is moved to top
       return 1;
   }
   function foo() {  // The second function declaration is moved to top
       return 2;
   }
   function outerFunction() {
       return foo();
   }
   alert(outerFunction()); //So executing from top to bottom,
                           //the last foo() returns 2 which gets displayed
   ```

   A function expression, if not defined before calling it, will result in an error. Also, here the function definition itself is not moved to the top or committed to memory like in the function declarations. But the variable to which we assign the function gets hoisted up and **undefined** gets assigned to it.

   Same function using function expressions:

   ```
   function outerFunction() {
       var foo = function() {
          return 1;
       }
       return foo();
       var foo = function() {
          return 2;
       }
   }
   alert(outerFunction()); // Displays 1
   ```

   This is because during execution, it looks like:

   ```
   function outerFunction() {
      var foo = undefined;
      var foo = undefined;

      foo = function() {
         return 1;
      };
      return foo ();
      foo = function() {   // This function expression is not reachable
         return 2;
      };
   }
   alert(outerFunction()); // Displays 1
   ```
2. It is not safe to write function declarations in non-function blocks like **if** because they won't be accessible.

   ```
   if (test) {
       function x() { doSomething(); }
   }
   ```
3. Named function expression like the one below, may not work in Internet Explorer browsers prior to version 9.

   ```
   var today = function today() {return new Date()}
   ```

Answer (score 15):

***About performance:***

New versions of `V8` introduced several under-the-hood optimizations and so did `SpiderMonkey`.

There is almost no difference now between expression and declaration. 
Function expression [appears to be faster](https://jsperf.com/fdeclaration-vs-fexpression) now.

***Chrome 62.0.3202***
[image: Chrome test]

***FireFox 55***
[image: Firefox test]

***Chrome Canary 63.0.3225***
[image: Chrome Canary test]

> `Anonymous` function expressions [appear to have better performance](https://jsperf.com/named-vs-anonymous-expressions)
>   against `Named` function expression.

***Firefox***
[image: Firefox named_anonymous]
***Chrome Canary***
[image: Chrome canary named_anonymous]
***Chrome***
[image: Chrome named_anonymous]

Comment: The results differences are too small to be considered as a difference. If you'll run the test 100 times, you will get 100 results.

Comment: @RonnySherer, are you familiar with jsperf? 
Tests were made after running more than 10 million times!

Comment: Every measurement has disturbances. The computer it not in the same state and this is not the only process running on the computer.
When the difference is so small, it means that you cannot rely on it and it is virtually the same.
Try to run the sane test 10 times one after the other and you'll see that the numbers are different. Pretty close, but not the same.

Comment: @RonnySherer js perf creates a virtual environment especially to account for processes with those small differences. It is not running on my computer. It runs only that. When something is so small maybe someone should not give a damn. BUT never the less I count it correctly and I report it. If someone wants to use it inside a loop with billions of iterations then he should pick the function with the best performance.

Comment: The virtual environment is on a server which might do some other stuff. I did some tests. The results are never exactly the same.

Answer (score 14):

If you would use those functions to create objects, you would get:

```
var objectOne = new functionOne();
console.log(objectOne.__proto__); // prints "Object {}" because constructor is an anonymous function

var objectTwo = new functionTwo();
console.log(objectTwo.__proto__); // prints "functionTwo {}" because constructor is a named function
```

Answer (score 14):

## Named Functions Vs. Anonymous Functions

The first function syntax is **Anonymous Function Expression**:

```
var functionOne = function() {
  // do something...
};
```

While, the second one is **Function Declaration**:

```
function functionTwo () {
  // do something...
}
```

The main difference between both is the function name since **Anonymous Functions** have no name to call.
Anonymous functions are quick and easy to declare, and many libraries and tools tend to encourage this idiomatic style of code. However, anonymous functions have some **drawbacks**:

- **Readability:** anonymous functions omit a name which could cause less readable code.
- **Debugging:** anonymous functions have no name in stack traces, which can make debugging more difficult.
- **Self-Reference:** what if the function needs to refer to itself, for recursion for example.

### Naming Function Expression

Providing a name for your function expression quite effectively addresses all these drawbacks, and has no tangible downsides. The best practice is to always name your function expressions:

```
setTimeout(function timeHandler() { // <-- look, a name here!
  console.log("I've waited 1 second");
}, 1000);
```

### Naming IIFEs (Immediate Invoked Function Expression)

```
(function IIFE(str) { // <-- look, always name IIFEs!
  console.log(str); // "Hello!"
})('Hello!');
```

For functions assigned to a variable, naming the function, in this case, is not very common and may cause confusion, in this case, the arrow function may be a better choice.

Answer (score 13):

In JavaScript there are two ways to create functions:

1. Function declaration:

   ```
   function fn(){
     console.log("Hello");
   }
   fn();
   ```

   This is very basic, self-explanatory, used in many languages and standard across C family of languages. We declared a function defined it and executed it by calling it.

   What you should be knowing is that functions are actually objects in JavaScript; internally we have created an object for above function and given it a name called fn or the reference to the object is stored in fn. Functions are objects in JavaScript; an instance of function is actually an object instance.
2. Function expression:

   ```
   var fn=function(){
     console.log("Hello");
   }
   fn();
   ```

   JavaScript has first-class functions, that is, create a function and assign it to a variable just like you create a string or number and assign it to a variable. Here, the fn variable is assigned to a function. The reason for this concept is functions are objects in JavaScript; fn is pointing to the object instance of the above function. We have initialized a function and assigned it to a variable. It's not executing the function and assigning the result.

Reference: *[JavaScript function declaration syntax: var fn = function() {} vs function fn() {}](http://jkoder.com/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn/)*

Answer (score 12):

In light of the "named functions show up in stack traces" argument, modern JavaScript engines are actually quite capable of representing anonymous functions.

As of this writing, V8, SpiderMonkey, Chakra and Nitro always refer to named functions by their names. They almost always refer to an anonymous function by its identifier if it has one.

SpiderMonkey can figure out the name of an anonymous function returned from another function. The rest can't.

If you really, really wanted your iterator and success callbacks to show up in the trace, you could name those too...

```
[].forEach(function iterator() {});
```

But for the most part it's not worth stressing over.

### Harness ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/us9dg6y8/))

```
'use strict';

var a = function () {
    throw new Error();
},
    b = function b() {
        throw new Error();
    },
    c = function d() {
        throw new Error();
    },
    e = {
        f: a,
        g: b,
        h: c,
        i: function () {
            throw new Error();
        },
        j: function j() {
            throw new Error();
        },
        k: function l() {
            throw new Error();
        }
    },
    m = (function () {
        return function () {
            throw new Error();
        };
    }()),
    n = (function () {
        return function n() {
            throw new Error();
        };
    }()),
    o = (function () {
        return function p() {
            throw new Error();
        };
    }());

console.log([a, b, c].concat(Object.keys(e).reduce(function (values, key) {
    return values.concat(e[key]);
}, [])).concat([m, n, o]).reduce(function (logs, func) {

    try {
        func();
    } catch (error) {
        return logs.concat('func.name: ' + func.name + '\n' +
                           'Trace:\n' +
                           error.stack);
        // Need to manually log the error object in Nitro.
    }

}, []).join('\n\n'));
```

### V8

```
func.name: 
Trace:
Error
    at a (http://localhost:8000/test.js:4:11)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27

func.name: b
Trace:
Error
    at b (http://localhost:8000/test.js:7:15)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27

func.name: d
Trace:
Error
    at d (http://localhost:8000/test.js:10:15)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27

func.name: 
Trace:
Error
    at a (http://localhost:8000/test.js:4:11)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27

func.name: b
Trace:
Error
    at b (http://localhost:8000/test.js:7:15)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27

func.name: d
Trace:
Error
    at d (http://localhost:8000/test.js:10:15)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27

func.name: 
Trace:
Error
    at e.i (http://localhost:8000/test.js:17:19)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27

func.name: j
Trace:
Error
    at j (http://localhost:8000/test.js:20:19)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27

func.name: l
Trace:
Error
    at l (http://localhost:8000/test.js:23:19)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27

func.name: 
Trace:
Error
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:28:19
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27

func.name: n
Trace:
Error
    at n (http://localhost:8000/test.js:33:19)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27

func.name: p
Trace:
Error
    at p (http://localhost:8000/test.js:38:19)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:27 test.js:42
```

### SpiderMonkey

```
func.name: 
Trace:
a@http://localhost:8000/test.js:4:5
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1


func.name: b
Trace:
b@http://localhost:8000/test.js:7:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1


func.name: d
Trace:
d@http://localhost:8000/test.js:10:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1


func.name: 
Trace:
a@http://localhost:8000/test.js:4:5
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1


func.name: b
Trace:
b@http://localhost:8000/test.js:7:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1


func.name: d
Trace:
d@http://localhost:8000/test.js:10:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1


func.name: 
Trace:
e.i@http://localhost:8000/test.js:17:13
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1


func.name: j
Trace:
j@http://localhost:8000/test.js:20:13
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1


func.name: l
Trace:
l@http://localhost:8000/test.js:23:13
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1


func.name: 
Trace:
m</<@http://localhost:8000/test.js:28:13
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1


func.name: n
Trace:
n@http://localhost:8000/test.js:33:13
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1


func.name: p
Trace:
p@http://localhost:8000/test.js:38:13
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9
@http://localhost:8000/test.js:54:1
```

### Chakra

```
func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at a (http://localhost:8000/test.js:4:5)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)


func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at b (http://localhost:8000/test.js:7:9)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)


func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at d (http://localhost:8000/test.js:10:9)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)


func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at a (http://localhost:8000/test.js:4:5)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)


func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at b (http://localhost:8000/test.js:7:9)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)


func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at d (http://localhost:8000/test.js:10:9)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)


func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at e.i (http://localhost:8000/test.js:17:13)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)


func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at j (http://localhost:8000/test.js:20:13)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)


func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at l (http://localhost:8000/test.js:23:13)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)


func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:28:13)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)


func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at n (http://localhost:8000/test.js:33:13)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)


func.name: undefined
Trace:
Error
   at p (http://localhost:8000/test.js:38:13)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:9)
   at Global code (http://localhost:8000/test.js:42:1)
```

### Nitro

```
func.name: 
Trace:
a@http://localhost:8000/test.js:4:22
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33

func.name: b
Trace:
b@http://localhost:8000/test.js:7:26
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33

func.name: d
Trace:
d@http://localhost:8000/test.js:10:26
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33

func.name: 
Trace:
a@http://localhost:8000/test.js:4:22
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33

func.name: b
Trace:
b@http://localhost:8000/test.js:7:26
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33

func.name: d
Trace:
d@http://localhost:8000/test.js:10:26
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33

func.name: 
Trace:
i@http://localhost:8000/test.js:17:30
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33

func.name: j
Trace:
j@http://localhost:8000/test.js:20:30
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33

func.name: l
Trace:
l@http://localhost:8000/test.js:23:30
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33

func.name: 
Trace:
http://localhost:8000/test.js:28:30
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33

func.name: n
Trace:
n@http://localhost:8000/test.js:33:30
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33

func.name: p
Trace:
p@http://localhost:8000/test.js:38:30
http://localhost:8000/test.js:47:13
reduce@[native code]
global code@http://localhost:8000/test.js:44:33
```

Answer (score 12):

Both are different ways of defining a function. The difference is how the browser interprets and loads them into an execution context.

The first case is of function expressions which loads only when the interpreter reaches that line of code. So if you do it like the following, you will get an error that the **functionOne is not a function**.

```
functionOne();
var functionOne = function() {
    // Some code
};
```

The reason is that on the first line no value is assigned to functionOne, and hence it is undefined. We are trying to call it as a function, and hence we are getting an error.

On the second line we are assigning the reference of an anonymous function to functionOne.

The second case is of function declarations that loads before any code is executed. So if you do like the following you won't get any error as the declaration loads before code execution.

```
functionOne();
function functionOne() {
   // Some code
}
```

Answer (score 11):

They are pretty similar with some small differences, first one is a variable which assigned to an anonymous function (Function Declaration) and second one is the normal way to create a function in JavaScript(Anonymous function Declaration), both has usage, cons and pros:

**1. Function Expression**

```
var functionOne = function() {
    // Some code
};
```

> A Function Expression defines a function as a part of a larger
>   expression syntax (typically a variable assignment ). Functions
>   defined via Functions Expressions can be named or anonymous. Function
>   Expressions must not start with “function” (hence the parentheses
>   around the self invoking example below).

Assign a variable to a function, means no Hoisting, as we know functions in JavaScript can Hoist, means they can be called before they get declared, while variables need to be declared before getting access to them, so means in this case we can not access the function before where it's declared, also it could be a way that you write your functions, for the functions which return another function, this kind of declaration could make sense, also in ECMA6 & above you can assign this to an arrow function which can be used to call anonymous functions, also this way of declaring is a better way to create Constructor functions in JavaScript.

**2. Function Declaration**

```
function functionTwo() {
    // Some code
}
```

> A Function Declaration defines a named function variable without
>   requiring variable assignment. Function Declarations occur as
>   standalone constructs and cannot be nested within non-function blocks.
>   It’s helpful to think of them as siblings of Variable Declarations.
>   Just as Variable Declarations must start with “var”, Function
>   Declarations must begin with “function”.

This is the normal way of calling a function in JavaScript, this function can be called before you even declare it as in JavaScript all functions get Hoisted, but if you have 'use strict' this won't Hoist as expected, it's a good way to call all normal functions which are not big in lines and neither are a  constructor function.

Also, if you need more info about how hoisting works in JavaScript, visit the link below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Answer (score 8):

This is just two possible ways of declaring functions, and in the second way, you can use the function before declaration.

Answer (score 7):

`new Function()` can be used to pass the function's body in a string. And hence this can be used to create dynamic functions. Also passing the script without executing the script.

```
var func = new Function("x", "y", "return x*y;");
function secondFunction(){
   var result;
   result = func(10,20);
   console.log ( result );
}

secondFunction()
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked here.

Answer (score 6):

This is called a Function Expression:

```
var getRectArea = function(width, height) {
    return width * height;
};

console.log("Area of Rectangle: " + getRectArea(3,4));
// This should return the following result in the console: 
// Area of Rectangle: 12
```

This is called a Function Declaration:

```
var w = 5;
var h = 6;

function RectArea(width, height) {  //declaring the function
  return area = width * height;
}                                   //note you do not need ; after }

RectArea(w,h);                      //calling or executing the function
console.log("Area of Rectangle: " + area);
// This should return the following result in the console: 
// Area of Rectangle: 30
```

Hope this helps explain what is the difference between Function Expression and Function Declaration and how to use them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer defining function as variable:

```
let first = function(x){
   return x[0];
}
```

Instead of:

```
function first(){
    ....
}
```

Because i can use expressions and decorators when defining the function. For example:

```
let safe = function(f){
  try {f()...}
}
let last = safe(function(x){return x[0]}).
```

Also with ES6 its much shorter:

```
 let last = x => x[0]
 ...........
 function last(x){
     return x[0];
 }
......

let last = safe(x => x[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

### Difference function declaration and function expression:

Javascript has first class functions. This means that they can be treated just like any other variable. Functions can be passed as arguments in a function, be returned from a function, **and can be stored in variables**.

However storing function in a variable (**function expression**) isn't the only way to create a function, this can also be done via a **function declaration**. Here are the key differences:

1. Function expressions can be anonymous whereas a function declaration must have a name.
2. Both have a name property which is used to identify the function. A function expression's name property is the name of the variable which it is bound to, whereas the name of a function declaration is simply the given name.
3. Function declarations are hoisted whereas, function expressions are not. Only the variable is hoisted to have the value of `undefined`.

Here is an example:

```js
try {
  functionOne();
} catch (e) {
  console.log('i cant run because im not hoisted');
}

functionTwo();

// function expression, does not get hoisted
let functionOne = function randomName() {
    // Some code
};

// function declaration, gets hoisted
function functionTwo() {
   console.log('I get hoisted');
}

try {
  randomName(); // this isn't the proper name, it is functionOne
} catch (e) {
  console.log('You cant call me with randomName my name is function one');
}
```

:

Comment: Declaration of `let functionOne` is hoisted. But it does not get initialized, not even with an `undefined` value. Hence, the error: _Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'functionOne' before initialization_

Answer (score 1):

**Expression in JS**:  Something that returns a value 
Example: Try out following in chrome console:

```
a = 10
output : 10

(1 + 3)
output = 4
```

**Declaration/Statement**: Something that does not return a value 
Example:

```
if (1 > 2) {
 // do something. 
}
```

here (1>2) is an expression but the 'if' statament is not. Its not returning anything.

Similarly, we have Function Declaration/Statement vs Function Expression 
Lets take an example:

```
// test.js

var a = 10;

// function expression
var fun_expression = function() {
   console.log("Running function Expression");
}

// funciton expression

function fun_declaration() {
   console.log("Running function Statement");
}
```

**Important:** 
What happens when JavaScript engines runs the above js file.

- When this js runs following things will happen:

  1. Memory will be created variable 'a' and 'fun_expression'. And memory will be created for function statement 'fun_declaration'
  2. 'a' will be assigned 'undefined'. 'fun_expression' will be assigned 'undefined'. 'fun_declaration' will be in the memory in its entirety. 
      
     **Note: Step 1 and 2 above are called 'Execution Context - Creation Phase'**.

Now suppose we update the js to.

```
// test.js

console.log(a)  //output: udefined (No error)
console.log(fun_expression)  // output: undefined (No error)
console.log(fun_expression()) // output: Error. As we trying to invoke undefined. 
console.log(fun_declaration()) // output: running function statement  (As fun_declaration is already hoisted in the memory). 

var a = 10;

// function expression
var fun_expression = function() {
   console.log('Running function expression')
}

// function declaration

function fun_declaration() {
   console.log('running function declaration')
}

console.log(a)   // output: 10
console.log(fun_expression()) //output: Running function expression
console.log(fun_declaration()) //output: running function declaration
```

The output mentioned above in the comments, should be useful to understand the different between function expression and function statement/declaration.

Answer (score 1):

One important point to note is :-

let there are two functions :-

```
sum(1,2);

const sum = function(first, second) {
  return first + second;
}
```

In above case, it will give error that sum is not defined, but

```
sum(1,2);

function sum(first, second) {
  return first + second;
}
```

This function will not any error as [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) will take place in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `.bind()` method on function declarations, but you can on function expressions.

Function declaration:

```js
function x() {
  console.log(this)
}.bind('string')

x()
```

Function expression:

```js
var x = function() {
  console.log(this)
}.bind('string')

x()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Debugger / DevTools

During a breakpoint in the debugger/DevTools, if you use the format `function functionName() {}` in the console, you can't use `functionName()` in the console subsequently (it says "not defined"), whereas after `var functionName = function() {}`, you can use the function.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68602479/5231110).

## Hoisting

More generally, the chosen notation might affect [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) behavior (i.e. from where the function can be called, depending on where it is defined).

Answer (score 0):

Another difference between both function is functionOne can be used as a variable that can hold multiple functions within and functionTwo holds some block of code that gets executed all when called. Please check below :

```
   var functionOne = (function() {
      return {

         sayHello: function(){
                console.log('say hello')

         },
         redirectPage:function(_url){
                window.location.href = _url;
         }

      }
})();
```

You have a choice which function to be called. e.g functionOne.sayHello or functionOne. redirectPage. And if you call functionTwo then whole block of code will get executed.

Answer (score 0):

The `var functionOne = function() {}` defines at run-time and the `function functionTwo() {}` defines at parse-time.

```js
// Run-Time function declaration 
functionOne(); // Calling functionOne function here will give an Error
var functionOne = function () {
  // Some code
};

// Parse-Time function declaration 
functionTwo(); // Calling functionTwo function will not give an Error
function functionTwo() {
  // Some code...
}
```

The explanation between Run-time vs Parse-time
[javascript run-time vs parse-time](http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/javascript-difference-between-runtime-and-parse-time)

Answer (score 0):

```js
try {
  console.log("Success: ", add(1, 1));
} catch(e) {
  console.log("ERROR: " + e);
}

var add=function(a, b){
  return a + b;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It's a code sample. It needs an explanation of what it is showing and also a counter example for the other type of declared function.

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between arrow function and normal function. In case of an arrow function, you are going to store a function inside a variable. I'm assuming that you have got your concepts clear for hoisting and execution context of JS. If not, please go through [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fnlnw8uY6jo&list=PLlasXeu85E9cQ32gLCvAvr9vNaUccPVNP&index=4) . Now, let me explain the execution context a bit.

The total execution of your code happens in two phases-

1. Memory allocation
2. Code execution

In case of memory allocation, you just need to assign the memory spaces. Like if you do have `var x = 4` in your code, after completing **phase 1** your program will know, `x = undefined`. So, it allocates a memory space for `x` but no values in it. Just like a house with no people.

Now, when the code execution phase starts, it will assign the value `4` in `x`. Same will happen if you store an arrow function in `x` instead of `4`. So that, you can get `undefined` if you try to call the arrow function on top of your program.

Now for the conventional function declaration, it will take place in phase one (Memory allocation) of the execution context. So, when the phase two starts, your program already knows what the function is and therefore you can console your function even before declaring it.

Hope it helps.