# What the difference between those two class definition?

Tags: javascript

```
var gem = function() {  
};

function gem() {    
};
```

It looks to me they are the same. but I know there must be some difference between those two?

Anyone knows which one is better?

Comment: I think both of them are same as each other and there is not deference between them.

Comment: Nit: neither of those is a "class". JavaScript does not have classes and any function can function as a constructor. The answers (thus far) therefor pertain to *all* functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The difference between the two functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114525/the-difference-between-the-two-functions)

Answer (score 11):

The first is an anonymous function that is part of an assignment expression. The function is created at the time of the assignment.

The second is a function declaration. It is "hoisted", which means its creation happens early, before any expression is evaluated.

---

Note the difference between this...

```
// TypeError, because the function has not been assigned
gem();

var gem = function() {};
```

and this...

```
// Works because the function declaration was hoisted.
gem();

function gem(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is very little difference. The `function name()` syntax will get "translated" into a `var name = function` statement by your JavaScript interpreter before the code is run.

If you want to know more about this, I can recommend this article: [JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) by *Ben Cherry*.

Note, by the way, that these are **functions, not classes**. JavaScript doesn't have classes, it has object inheritance.

Comment: @Adam: yes, you can [use functions as constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function) to create new object. But it's still a function, not a class. :-)