# angularjs [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js..I am getting follwing error please help me out

[ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string

```
var app = angular.module('demo',[]);


app.config('$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/add',{
        templateUrl:'demo/add.html',
        controller:'addcontroller'
    }).
    when('/order',{
        templateUrl:'demo/order.html',
        controller:'ordercontroller'
    });

});

app.controller('addcontroller',function($scope){
    $scope.message="order";
});
app.controller('ordercontroller',function($scope){
    $scope.message="order";
});
```

Comment: Where and when do you get that error?

Answer (score 34):

I think the error is in the config block, it should either be:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  // routeProvider config
});
```

or better:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  // routeProvider config, allows minification
}]);
```

the annotations are there for minification to work correctly. You can read more about it on AngularJS docs https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 
Please note that this practice needs to be done throughout the app to work correctly.

Answer (score 15):

Although not directly related to the context of this question, this error message can also be caused by a resolve block returning something else than a function, like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('mystate', {
    url: "/myurl",
    templateUrl: "mytemplate.html",
    controller: "MyController",
    resolve: {
        authenticatedUser: securityAuthorizationProvider.requireAuthenticatedUser
    }
});
```

if `securityAuthorizationProvider.requireAuthenticatedUser` happens to be undefined, you can get this error.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older post, but thought I'd contribute what was wrong with my code with this exact error.  I was injecting a service into my controller this way:

```
theApp.directive('theDirective', 'myService', ['$http', function ($http, myService) {}]);
```

Instead of this:

```
theApp.directive('theDirective', ['$http', 'myService', function ($http, myService) {}]);
```

Notice that my service was included **outside** of the inline array annotation!  It was a boneheaded move on my part that cost me way too much time.

Answer (score 2):

For the the problem was defining factory dependency outside the array. Most probably the minification was also an issue.

```
//Error in this
  angular
    .module('mymodule').factory('myFactory', 'thisconstant', function (thisconstant) {

});
```

This fixed by

```
//correct code
  angular
    .module('mymodule').factory('myFactory', ['thisconstant', function (thisconstant) {

}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there's been various use cases added here, I thought I'd also add mine. I got this error when re-formating a function service

```
angular
.app('myApp')
.service('MyService', function (){
  // do something
return MyService;
})
```

into a class object:

```
export default class MyService { ... }

angular
    .app('myApp')
    .service('MyService', MyService);
```

My problem was that my service was returning itself at the end of the function and I needed to add a class function, which would do this:

```
export default class MyService {
  constructor(){
  // doing something
  }

  get() {
  return MyService;
  }
}
```

which fixed the issue for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error by misunderstanding the way anonymous functions and named functions are treated in JavaScript.

This causes the error:

```
angular.module("app").factory("myDataService", ['$resource', myDataService]);
var myDataService = function($resource) {
    return $resource('/url');
}
```

I should've either done this:

```
var myDataService = function($resource) {
    return $resource('/url');
}
angular.module("app").factory("myDataService", ['$resource', myDataService]);
```

Or this:

```
angular.module("app").factory("myDataService", ['$resource', myDataService]);
function myDataService($resource) {
    return $resource('/url');
}
```

More on the difference between anonymous function and named function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114593/3154611)

Answer (score 1):

In First line you need to use like this,

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute']);
```

and use the routing thing like this,

```
$routeProvider.when('/add').then({
        templateUrl:'demo/add.html',
        controller:'addcontroller'
    });
```

Just try these steps once.